# Proving an alternating Euler sum: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1} H_k}{k} = \frac{1}{2} \zeta(2) - \frac{1}{2} \log^2 2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers, euler-sums

Let $$A(p,q) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}H^{(p)}_k}{k^q},$$
where $H^{(p)}_n = \sum_{i=1}^n i^{-p}$, the $n$th $p$-harmonic number.  The $A(p,q)$'s are known as *alternating [Euler sums](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerSum.html)*.

> Can someone provide a nice proof that 
>   $$A(1,1) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1} H_k}{k} = \frac{1}{2} \zeta(2) - \frac{1}{2} \log^2 2?$$

I worked for a while on this today but was unsuccessful.  Summation by parts, swapping the order of summation, and approximating $H_k$ by $\log k$ were my best ideas, but I could not get any of them to work.  (Perhaps someone else can?)  I would like a nice proof in order to complete [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274742/evaluate-int-01-ln1-x-ln-x-ln1x-mathrmdx/275641#275641).

Bonus points for proving $A(1,2) = \frac{5}{8} \zeta(3)$ and $A(2,1) =  \zeta(3) - \frac{1}{2}\zeta(2) \log 2$, as those are the other two alternating Euler sums needed to complete my answer.

---

**Added**: I'm going to change the accepted answer to robjohn's $A(1,1)$ calculation as a proxy for the three answers he gave here.  Notwithstanding the other great answers (especially the currently most-upvoted one, the one I first accepted), robjohn's approach is the one I was originally trying.  I am pleased to see that it can be used to do the $A(1,1)$, $A(1,2)$, and $A(2,1)$ derivations.

Comment: Write out the infinite product $\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1-x^k/k^s)$ in terms of the gamma function, use veitas formulas to gather up partial sums of 1/k^s, and align them with the products corresponding power series, euler did something similar to solve the basel problem. Try doing it for the case s=2, in which case the product is sin(pi*x)/(pi*x).

Comment: @Ethan: Spell out the details, and perhaps that becomes an answer? :)

Comment: Can you inculde the  defintion of $A(p,q)$ ?

Comment: @Ethan I missed that

Comment: The definition is already stated

Comment: It is interesting that this question has been marked as a favorite $6$ favorites whereas it only has $4$ up-votes.

Comment: @Marvis: I suspect it's because of your answer rather than the question itself. :)

Comment: I wonder if we should have a tag called "Euler sums". Moreover, it seems to be a realm less explored.

Comment: @Chris'ssister: I'm neutral on that.  But if you want to create such a tag, go ahead.

Comment: @MikeSpivey: After searching several days, I was able to find a relating and very interesting approach from David M. Bradley, see [this link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/1758087_A_q-Analog_of_Euler%27s_Reduction_Formula_for_the_Double_Zeta_Function).

Answer (score 92, accepted):

**$A(1,1)$:**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}H_n
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}+\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}H_{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}+\frac12\sum_{n=2}^N\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\left(\frac1k+\frac1{n-k}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}+\frac12\sum_{n=2}^N\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{k(n-k)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\sum_{n=k+1}^N\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{k(n-k)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\sum_{n=1}^{N-k}\frac{(-1)^{n+k-1}}{kn}\\
&=\color{#00A000}{\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}}
-\color{#0000FF}{\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}}\\
&+\color{#C00000}{\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\sum_{n=N-k+1}^{N-1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
where, using the Alternating Series Test, we have
$$
\begin{align}
&\color{#C00000}{\frac12\left|\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\sum_{n=N-k+1}^{N-1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\right|}\\
&\le\frac12\left|\sum_{k=1}^{N/2}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\sum_{n=N-k+1}^{N-1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\right|
+\frac12\left|\sum_{k=N/2}^{N-1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\sum_{n=N-k+1}^{N-1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\right|\\
&\le\frac12\cdot1\cdot\frac2N+\frac12\cdot\frac2N\cdot1\\
&=\frac2N\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Applying $(2)$ to $(1)$ and letting $N\to\infty$, we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}H_n=\color{#00A000}{\frac12\zeta(2)}-\color{#0000FF}{\frac12\log(2)^2}\tag{3}
$$

Comment: Very nice answer! I hope it will be highly upvoted!

Comment: @Chris'ssis: thanks. I'm not holding my breath since I came across this question so late.

Comment: very good answer (+1) .

Comment: Rob, this is very nice!  I particularly like the fact that it is the kind of approach I was originally trying but couldn't get to work.  For others reading this, what Rob has done is to extract the eta function partial sum and then show that the rest turns into the square of the partial sum of the alternating harmonic series plus change.  It's really clear how the answer falls out this way.  Beautiful.

Comment: @MikeSpivey: Thanks for the comments and corrections! Let me know if you find anything that needs explanation for my derivation of $A(1,2)$.

Answer (score 97):

Note that
$$\dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}k = \int_0^1 (-x)^{k-1}dx$$
and
$$\dfrac1n = \int_0^1 y^{n-1}dy$$

---

For the first one,
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}k \sum_{n=1}^k \dfrac1n & = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^k \int_0^1 (-x)^{k-1}dx \int_0^1 y^{n-1} dy\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \int_0^1 (-x)^{k-1}dx \int_0^1 y^{n-1} dy\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^1 \dfrac{(-x)^{n-1}}{1+x}dx \int_0^1 y^{n-1} dy\\
& = \int_0^1 \int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-xy)^{n-1}}{1+x}dx dy\\
& = \int_0^1 \int_0^1\dfrac1{(1+x)(1+xy)}dx dy\\
& = \int_0^1 \int_0^1\dfrac1{(1+x)(1+xy)}dy dx\\
& = \int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+x)}{x(1+x)} dx\\
& = \int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+x)}{x} dx - \int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+x)}{(1+x)} dx\\
& = \dfrac{\zeta(2)}2 - \dfrac{\log^2 2}2
\end{align}

$$\int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+x)}{x} dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 \dfrac{(-1)^kx^k}{k+1} dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^2} = \dfrac{\zeta(2)}2$$
$$\int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+x)}{(1+x)} dx = \left. \dfrac{\log^2(1+x)}2 \right \vert_{x=0}^{x=1} = \dfrac{\log^2 2}2$$

---

For the second one,

$$A(1,2) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2} \sum_{n=1}^k \dfrac1n $$
$$\dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^2} = \int_0^1 (-x)^{k-1} dx \int_0^1 z^{k-1} dz = (-1)^{k-1} \int_0^1 \int_0^1 (xz)^{k-1} dx dz$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2} \sum_{n=1}^k \dfrac1n & = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^k \int_0^1\int_0^1 (-1)^{k-1} (xz)^{k-1}dxdz \int_0^1 y^{n-1} dy\\
& = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-xyz)^{n-1}}{1+xz} dx dy dz\\
& = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \dfrac1{(1+xz)(1+xyz)} dx dy dz\\
& = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+xz)}{xz(1+xz)} dx dz\\
& = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+xz)}{xz} dx dz - \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+xz)}{1+xz} dx dz\\
& = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+xz)}{xz} dx dz- \int_0^1 \dfrac{\log^2(1+z)}{2z} dz\\
& = \dfrac34 \zeta(3) - \dfrac{\zeta(3)}8\\
& = \dfrac58 \zeta(3)
\end{align}

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+xz)}{xz} dx dz = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \dfrac{(-1)^k (xz)^k}{k+1} dx dz = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^3} = \dfrac34 \zeta(3)$$

---

For the third one,
$$A(2,1) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \sum_{n=1}^k \dfrac1{n^2} $$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \sum_{n=1}^k \dfrac1{n^2} & = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^k (-1)^{k-1} x^{k-1} (yz)^{n-1} dx dy dz\\
& = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} x^{k-1} (yz)^{n-1} dx dy dz\\
& = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-xyz)^{n-1}}{1+x} dx dy dz\\
& = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \dfrac1{(1+x)(1+xyz)} dx dy dz\\
& = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+xy)}{(1+x)(xy)} dx dy\\
& = \zeta(3) - \dfrac{\zeta(2) \log 2}2
\end{align}

---

In general, if I have not made any mistake, this can be extended to $A(p,q)$.
$$A(p,q) = \underbrace{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1}_{p+q \text{ times}} \dfrac{dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_{p+q}}{(1+x_1 x_2 \cdots x_q)(1+x_1 x_2 \cdots x_{p+q})}$$

---

Proceeding along similar lines, we also get that $$B(p,q) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{H_k^{(p)}}{k^q} = \underbrace{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1}_{p+q \text{ times}} \dfrac{dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_{p+q}}{(1-x_1 x_2 \cdots x_q)(1-x_1 x_2 \cdots x_{p+q})}$$

---

We also get that $$C(p,q) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{k^q} \sum_{i=1}^k \dfrac{(-1)^{i-1}}{i^p} = \underbrace{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1}_{p+q \text{ times}} \dfrac{dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_{p+q}}{(1-x_1 x_2 \cdots x_q)(1+x_1 x_2 \cdots x_{p+q})}$$
$$D(p,q) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^q} \sum_{i=1}^k \dfrac{(-1)^{i-1}}{i^p} = \underbrace{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1}_{p+q \text{ times}} \dfrac{dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_{p+q}}{(1+x_1 x_2 \cdots x_q)(1-x_1 x_2 \cdots x_{p+q})}$$

---

By the same argument as above, in general, nested sums like $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(\pm 1)^{k-1}}{k^q} \sum_{n=1}^k \dfrac{(\pm 1)^{n-1}}{n^p} \sum_{m=1}^n \dfrac{(\pm 1)^{m-1}}{m^r} \cdots $$ equals
$$\underbrace{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1}_{p+q+r+\cdots \text{ times}} \dfrac{dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_{p+q+r+\cdots}}{(1\mp x_1 \cdots x_q)(1(\mp)(\pm)x_1 \cdots x_{p+q}) \cdots (1(\mp)(\pm)\cdots(\pm)x_1 \cdots x_{p+q+r+\cdots})}$$

For instance,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k^q} \sum_{n=1}^k \dfrac{1}{n^p} \sum_{m=1}^n \dfrac{1}{m^r} = \underbrace{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1}_{p+q+r \text{ times}} \dfrac{dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_{p+q+r}}{(1- x_1 \cdots x_q)(1-x_1 \cdots x_{p+q}) \cdots (1-x_1 \cdots x_{p+q+r})}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^q} \sum_{n=1}^k \dfrac{1}{n^p} \sum_{m=1}^n \dfrac{1}{m^r} = \underbrace{\int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1}_{p+q+r \text{ times}} \dfrac{dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_{p+q+r}}{(1+ x_1 \cdots x_q)(1+x_1 \cdots x_{p+q}) \cdots (1+x_1 \cdots x_{p+q+r})}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^q} \sum_{n=1}^k \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^p} \sum_{m=1}^n \dfrac{1}{m^r} = \underbrace{\int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1}_{p+q+r \text{ times}} \dfrac{dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_{p+q+r}}{(1+ x_1 \cdots x_q)(1-x_1 \cdots x_{p+q}) \cdots (1-x_1 \cdots x_{p+q+r})}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k^q} \sum_{n=1}^k \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^p} \sum_{m=1}^n \dfrac{1}{m^r} = \underbrace{\int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1}_{p+q+r \text{ times}} \dfrac{dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_{p+q+r}}{(1- x_1 \cdots x_q)(1+x_1 \cdots x_{p+q}) \cdots (1+x_1 \cdots x_{p+q+r})}$$

---

Similarly, for negative $p$,$q$ $r$ etc, we can replace the integrals $\int_0^1$ by the appropriate differentiation operator evaluated at $1$. I will post this in detail sometime over the weekend.

Comment: very nice lol, much better then my idea

Comment: @Marvis: a powerful answer. We need such answers on MSE. (+1)

Comment: This is truly a beautiful answer, Marvis.  Thank you.  One thing, though: Do you have references for those integral evaluations you end each of your derivations with?  I'm not that familiar with them.

Comment: @MikeSpivey At least for $A(1,1), A(1,2)$ and $A(2,1)$, the integrals that arise can actually be evaluated by direct methods. I will add them for detail.

Comment: @Marvis:  If you want to, that would be great.  If you just want to give some hints or an outline, that would also be great.  Your answer is already more than I had expected, so anything else would just be icing on the cake.  Again, wonderful answer, and thank you.

Comment: @MikeSpivey There are three more integrals to be evaluated, which probably will need some basic properties of the poly-logarithm function (or there might be some trick here as well to evaluate them). I will add them tonight. It will also be interesting to look at the nested Euler sums and see how this gets reflected in terms of the derivatives and integrals as I have mentioned in the last paragraph.

Comment: I am completely astounded by this brilliant answer! I also succeeded in calculating those series by using dilogarithm identities and trilogarithm identity, my solutions lack a systematic approach that your illuminating answer shows. That's why I love this answer.

Comment: @sos440 I now recall that we did a similar problem [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263536/how-to-calculate-i-frac12-int-0-frac-pi-2-frac-ln-sin-y-ln-co) where we wanted to evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{H_k}{k^2}$, but we did it by a slightly different method over there.

Comment: @MikeSpivey From the wolfram article I see that the Euler sums are slight different since it consider sums of the form $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{H_k^p}{k^q}$$ whereas this one is $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{H_k^{(p)}}{k^q}$$Are these also called as Euler sums?

Comment: @Marvis: Yes, look further at the article, and you'll see that both kinds are considered Euler sums.  One's denoted $s$ and the other $\sigma$.

Comment: This deserves a place in american mathematical monthly

Comment: Thanks Norbert. I too was thinking to submit it or just post it on arxiv along with @MikeSpivey. But I don't think I have enough time now to write this up. So this will have to wait for a while. :-)

Comment: I feel completely overwhelmed solely by skimming this answer, Marvis. Dare I call it beautiful, for I know not what it is . . .

Comment: @MikeSpivey You might be already aware of this but still the following link has some useful informations on Euler sums. http://www.usna.edu/Users/math/meh/biblio.html
There is also an open conjecture termed sum and duality conjectures mentioned in this article http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.pjm/1102636166

Comment: @Marvis: Do you have time now to follow up on your comment about writing this up?  I'll be in chat for a bit so that we can talk about that.

Comment: @MikeSpivey Sure. Are you on chat?

Comment: My answer seems like a dinghy next to your aircraft carrier :-)

Answer (score 40):

**$A(1,2)$:**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}H_n
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+n}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{nk(k+n)}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty\frac1{nk(n-k)}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{nk(n-k)}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{n^2}\left(\frac1k+\frac1{n-k}\right)\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}H_{n-1}\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}H_n-2\zeta(3)\tag{2}\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}H_n
&=2\zeta(3)\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}H_n
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+n}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{nk(k+n)}\tag{4}\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}H_n
&=-\frac34\zeta(3)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}H_{n-1}\\
&=-\frac34\zeta(3)+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\left(\frac1k+\frac1{n-k}\right)\\
&=-\frac34\zeta(3)+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{nk(n-k)}\\
&=-\frac34\zeta(3)+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{(n+k)kn}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Using $\color{#C00000}{(1)}$, $\color{#C00000}{(3)}$, $\color{#00A000}{(4)}$, $\color{#0000FF}{(4)}$, and $\color{#C0A000}{(5)}$ along with the fact that $1+(-1)^k+(-1)^n+(-1)^{n+k}=4$ iff $k$ and $n$ are both even and $0$ otherwise:
$$
\begin{align}
\zeta(3)
&=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{nk(n+k)}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\color{#C00000}{1}+\color{#00A000}{(-1)^k}+\color{#0000FF}{(-1)^n}+\color{#C0A000}{(-1)^{n+k}}}{nk(n+k)}\\
&=\color{#C00000}{2\zeta(3)}+\color{#00A000}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}H_n}+\color{#0000FF}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}H_n}
+\color{#C0A000}{2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}H_n+\frac32\zeta(3)}\\
\hspace{-8mm}-\frac58\zeta(3)
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}H_n\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
That is,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}H_n=\frac58\zeta(3)\tag{7}
$$

Comment: An amazing answer! (+1) If I could I'd upvote it $1000$ times.

Comment: @Chris'ssis: I spent pretty much all day yesterday on this sum for a question you asked in chat, then saw that it was asked in this question, too! :-)

Comment: an amazing answer (+1)

Comment: Again, very nice!  It would never have occurred to me to use the property that $1 + (-1)^k + (-1)^n + (-1)^{n+k} = 4$ when $n$ and $k$ are even and vanishes otherwise.  Well done.

Comment: @robjohn very nice solution.  I was wondering of a variation of what you did here except the summation over odd integers (not all integers as done here) and the sum in $H_n$ is summed over odd integers only also.  
$$
\sum_{n=1(odd)}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2}
$$
Thanks. I was hoping the answer to be similar to what you did but I am not sure how to work with the summations

Comment: @Jeff: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/469785) with $q=2$, then note that $$\sum_{n\text { odd}}a_n=\frac12\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}a_n\right)$$

Answer (score 35):

Using integral representation:
$$
A(1,1)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} H_n = -\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-x)^n H_n \frac{\mathrm{d} x }{x}
$$
Now:
$$
  -\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-x)^n H_n = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{n-k} = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x)^n \cdot \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-x)^k}{k}  = \frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x}
$$
Thus
$$
   A(1,1) = \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x} = \left. \left(-\frac{1}{2} \log^2(1+x) - \operatorname{Li}_2(-x) \right)\right|_{x = 0}^{x=1} = -\frac{1}{2} \log^2(2) - \operatorname{Li}_2(-1)
$$
But $\operatorname{Li}_2(-1) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k^2} = \left(2^{1-2}-1\right) \zeta(2) = -\frac{1}{2} \zeta(2)$. Thus$$
  A(1,1) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \zeta(2) - \log^2(2)\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks, Sasha.  One question, though: I don't follow the step $-\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{n-k} = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x)^n \cdot \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-x)^k}{k}$.

Comment: Never mind; I got it.  You're using the product formula for power series.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 21):

Actually it suffices to know the generating function

$$\sum_{k\geq 1}H^{(p)}_kx^k=\frac{\mathrm{Li}_p(x)}{1-x}$$

Upon integrating we obtain

$$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{H^{(p)}_k}{k}x^k=\mathrm{Li}_{p+1}(x)+\int^x_0 \frac{\mathrm{Li}_p(t)}{1-t}\,d t$$

$$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{H_k}{k}x^k=\mathrm{Li}_{2}(x)+\frac{1}{2}\log^2(1-x)$$

$$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{H_k}{k}(-1)^k=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{1}{2}\log^2(2)$$

Comment: Typo on the last line. Should be $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{H_k}{k}(-1)^k$, I believe.

Comment: @columbus8myhw, thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Related problems: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305476/about-a-harmonic-series-problem-how-to-prove-that-sum-n-1-infty-frach/305627#305627), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465490/evaluating-int1-0-frac-operatornameli-3x1-x-logx-mathrm-dx/465525#465525), [(III)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858945/how-find-this-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n-1-zeta-n3n/859341#859341), [(IV)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314543/a-series-involves-harmonic-number), [$(5)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909228/a-sum-containing-harmonic-numbers-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nn3-2n/909352#909352). For $A(1, 1)$, one can have the integral representation

> $$ A(1,1) = \int _{1}^{2}\!{\frac {\ln  \left( t \right) }{t \left( t-1 \right) }}
> {dw}.$$

In general, one can have the following representation for $A(p,1)$

> $$ A(p,1) = -\int _{0}^{1}\!{\frac { Li_{p}\left( -u \right) }{ \left( 1+
> u \right) u}}{du},$$

where $Li_{p}(-u)$ is the [polylogarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). Here are some numerical values for $p$ from $1$ to $5$

$$ 0.5822405265,\, 0.6319661978,\, 0.6603570751,\, 0.6759332433,\, 0.6842426955. $$

**The General Case A(p,q):**

> $$ A(p,q) =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}H^{(p)}_k}{k^q} = \frac{\left( -1 \right) ^{q}}{\Gamma(q)}\int _{0}^{1}\!{\frac { \left( \ln\left( u
>  \right)  \right)^{q-1}{Li_{p}(-u)} }{ u\left( 1+
> u \right) }}{du}. $$

Some numerical values

$$ A(1,2) = .7512855645,\, A(2, 3) = .8793713030, \, A(3, 4) = .9407280160, $$

$$ A(2,1) = .6319661978, A(3, 2) = .8024944234, A(4, 3) = .8956823180. $$

**Added**

**The General Case B(p,q):**

> $$ B(p,q) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{H_k^{(p)}}{k^q}=\frac{(-1)^q}{\Gamma(q)}\int_{0}^{1}\!{\frac {\left(\ln\left(u\right)\right)^{q-1}{Li_{p}(u)} }{ u\left( u-1 \right)}}{du}. $$

Some numerical values

$$ B(1, 2) = 2.404113806, B(2, 3) = 1.265738152, B(3, 4) = 1.093509100, $$

$$ B(3, 2) = 1.748493953, B(4, 3) = 1.215854292, B(5, 4) = 1.084986223. $$

Comment: Thanks, but that's already in part of Marvis's answer.

Comment: @MikeSpivey: You are welcome. See the more general case $A(p,1)$.

Comment: Your generalization to the $A(p,1)$ case is interesting.  Do you have a proof or reference for that?

Comment: A proof for $A(p,1)$ is as follows. $$A(p,1) = \underbrace{\int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1}_{p+1 \text{ times}} \int_0^1 \dfrac{dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_{p+1}}{(1+x_1)(1+x_1x_2x_3 \cdots x_{p+1})}$$
Now $$\underbrace{\int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1}_{p \text{ times}} \int_0^1 \dfrac{dx_2 dx_3 \cdots dx_{p+1}}{(1+x_1x_2x_3 \cdots x_{p})} = -\dfrac{\text{Li}_p(-x_1)}{x_1}$$ which follows immediately from induction and definition of $\text{Li}_n(x)$.

Comment: @Marvis: Thanks. +1 to Mhenni's answer.

Comment: Note that $$-\dfrac{Li_p(-u)}{u(1+u)} = -\dfrac{Li_p(-u)}{u} + \dfrac{Li_p(-u)}{1+u}$$
Hence, $$A(p,1) = (1-2^{-p}) \zeta(1+p) + \int_0^1 \dfrac{Li_p(-u)}{1+u} du$$

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Nice expression for a general $(p,q)$. +1. Could you throw some light on how you obtained it?

Comment: @Marvis: Thanks for the comment. I'll try to do this latter. It is a nice problem.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal If what you have is true, it should be possible to express, $B,C$ and $D$ and all the rest of the nested sums as well, as elegant as you have, instead of a sequence of integrals.

Comment: @Marvis: I'll be working on them and see what we get.

Comment: @user17762: Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Downvoter: These are very useful integral representations. I do not know what the downvote is for.

Answer (score 14):

$A(2,1)$:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n}
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^3}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{n-1}^{(2)}}{n}\tag{1}\\
&=\frac34\zeta(3)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{k^2}\tag{2}\\
&=\frac34\zeta(3)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{nk^2}\tag{3}\\
&=\frac34\zeta(3)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+n-1}}{(k+n)k^2}\tag{4}\\
&=\frac34\zeta(3)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+n-1}\left(\frac1{k^2n}-\frac1{kn(k+n)}\right)\tag{5}\\[6pt]
&=\frac34\zeta(3)-\frac12\zeta(2)\log(2)+\frac14\zeta(3)\tag{6}\\[9pt]
&=\zeta(3)-\frac12\zeta(2)\log(2)\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Justification:
$(1)$: $H_n^{(2)}=\frac1{n^3}+H_{n-1}^{(2)}$
$(2)$: expand $H_{n-1}^{(2)}$
$(3)$: change order of summation
$(4)$: reindex $n\mapsto k+n$
$(5)$: $\frac1{(k+n)k^2}=\frac1{k^2n}-\frac1{kn(k+n)}$
$(6)$: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+n}}{kn(k+n)}=\frac14\zeta(3)$ from $(5)$ and $(7)$ of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/499716)
$(7)$: addition

Note that this answer was taken from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/609938).  There, it is shown, using the [Euler Series Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration#Euler.27s_transform), that
$$
A(2,1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{2^nn^2}\tag{8}
$$

Comment: Thanks, Rob.  I appreciate you taking the time to add this answer.

Comment: @robjohn I always enjoy reading your posts, not only for their creative content, but also the style you've adopted to facilitate the reader's understanding of the development.  And I've notice that you often embed references to previously answered questions.  Rob, this might not be the right place to ask, but how do you keep track of your posted answers?  I've posted now a bit over 1,000 answers and find it challenging to find the one or ones that I can use as a reference when replying to a new question.  Is their a "search" method that you use or have you developed a some catalogue?

Comment: @Dr.MV: I used to try to keep track of the answers that I thought I might reference by marking the questions as favorites. However, that started getting crowded, so I keep a number of answers in an offline catalogue. That allows for better organization and easier searching.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks Rob.  I'd like to know more about how you organize, but that is likely asking too much.  I'll see if I can implement a scheme that works well.

Answer (score 14):

Interestingly, $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}H_{n}^{-}}{n} = \frac{\zeta(2)}{2} {\color{red}{+}} \frac{\log^{2} (2)}{2}$$ where $H_{n}^{-}$ are the alternating harmonic numbers defined as $$H_{n}^{-} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} .$$

One way to show this is to notice that $$ \begin{align} \log (2) - H_{n}^{-}  &= \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \\ &= (-1)^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k+n} \\ &= (-1)^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} \int_{0}^{1} x^{k+n-1} \ dx \\ &= (-1)^{n} \int_{0}^{1} x^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1} x^{k-1} \ dx \\ &= (-1)^{n} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{n}}{1+x} \ dx . \end{align}$$

Thus an integral representation of the alternating harmonic numbers is $$ H_{n}^{-} = \log (2) + (-1)^{n-1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{n}}{1+x} \ dx .$$

The integral on the right can be evaluated in terms of the digamma function, and you'll get a closed-form expression for the alternating harmonic numbers.

But getting back to evaluating that sum,

$$ \begin{align} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}H_{n}^{-}}{n} &= \log(2) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{n}}{1+x} \ dx \\ &= \log^{2} (2) + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n} \ dx \\ &= \log^{2} (2) - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log (1-x)}{1+x} \ dx \\  &=\log^{2} 2 - \int_{1/2}^{1} \frac{\log \big(1-(2t-1) \big)}{2t} \ 2 \ dt \\ &= \log^{2}(2) - \int_{1/2}^{1} \frac{\log \big(2(1-t) \big)}{t} \ dt \\ &= \log^{2}(2) - \int_{1/2}^{1} \frac{\log 2}{t} \ dt - \int_{1/2}^{1} \frac{\log (1-t)}{t} \ dt \\ &= \log^{2}(2) - \log^{2}(2) + \text{Li}_{2}(1) - \text{Li}_{2} \left( \frac{1}{2}\right) \\ &=  \zeta(2) - \frac{\zeta(2)}{2} + \frac{\log^{2} (2)}{2} \\ &= \frac{\zeta (2)}{2} + \frac{\log^{2} (2)}{2} . \end{align}$$

Comment: That is interesting.  Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 13):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k + 1} H_{\rm k} \over k}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k + 1} H_{\rm k}\over k}}
> =\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k + 1} \over k}
> \int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{k} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k + 1} \over k}\int_{0}^{1}
> \ln\pars{1 - t}\pars{-kt^{k - 1}}\,\dd t
> =-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 - t}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-t}^{k - 1}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=-\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over 1 + t}\,\dd t
> =-\,\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{t} \over 2 - t}\,\dd t
> =-\,\int_{0}^{1/2}{\ln\pars{2t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
> =-\,\int_{0}^{1/2}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{1/2}{{\rm Li}_{1}\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{{\rm Li}_{s}\pars{z}}$ is a
>   [PolyLogarithm Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#CITEREFSchr.C3.B6dinger1952) and we'll use well known properties of them as explained in the above mentioned link.

Then,
$$
\color{#c00000}{%
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k + 1} H_{\rm k}\over k}}
=\int_{0}^{1/2}{\rm Li}_{2}'\pars{t}\,\dd t
={\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\half} - {\rm Li}_{2}\pars{0}
=\color{#c00000}{{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\half}}
$$

> $\ds{{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\half}}$ is given in the above mentioned link:
>   \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
> \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k + 1} H_{\rm k}\over k}}
> ={\pi^{2} \over 12} - \half\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}
> =\color{#66f}{\large\half\bracks{\zeta\pars{2} - \ln^{2}\pars{2}}}
> \end{align}

Comment: How do you go from $\int_0^1 \frac{1-t^k}{1-t} \, dt$ to $\int_0^1 \ln(1-t) (-kt^{k-1}) \, dt$ in the second step?

Comment: @MikeSpivey Integrating by parts since $\displaystyle\large{{\rm d}\ln\left(1 - t\right) \over {\rm d}t} = -\,{1 \over 1 - t}$. Thanks.

Comment: Got it; thanks!  And +1.

Answer (score 7):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}H_k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}H_k\int_0^1 x^{k-1}dx\\=\int_0^1\frac1x\sum_{k=1}^\infty{-H_k (-x)^{k}}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx\\=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx\\=-\operatorname{Li}_2(-1)-\frac12\ln^22\\=\frac12\zeta(2)-\frac12\ln^22$$

where we used the identity $\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_nx^n=-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1-x}$ and the value $\operatorname{Li}_2(-1)=-\frac12\zeta(2)$

Answer (score 5):

A full derivation of $A(m,1), \ m\ge2$, is found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3236584),
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n^{(m)}}{n}=\frac{(-1)^m}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{\displaystyle \log^{m-1}(x)\log\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}{1-x}\textrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{1}{2}\biggr(m\zeta (m+1)-2\log (2) \left(1-2^{1-m}\right) \zeta (m)-\sum_{k=1}^{m-2} \left(1-2^{-k}\right)\left(1-2^{1+k-m}\right)\zeta (k+1)\zeta (m-k)\biggr),
\end{equation*}
where $H_n^{(m)}=1+\frac{1}{2^m}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^m}$ represents the $n$th generalized harmonic number of order $m$ and $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function.

Also, a full solution to the case

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} \frac{H_k}{k^{2n}}=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\eta(2n+1)-\frac{1}{2}\zeta(2n+1)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\eta(2k)\zeta(2n-2k+1), \ n\ge1.
\end{equation*}

may be found in Cornel's new article [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333999069_A_new_powerful_strategy_of_calculating_a_class_of_alternating_Euler_sums).

Comment: *"At a later date"* is not really good. In particular, how to you go from $\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac {H_n} n$ to $\sum _{k=1} ^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} \frac {H_k} {k^{2n}}$?

Answer (score 4):

For $A(1,2)$:

Using $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_nx^n=-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1-x}$$

replace $x$ with $-x$ then multiply both sides by $-\frac{\ln x}{x}$ and integrate between $0$ and $1$ and use the fact that $\int_0^1 -x^{n-1}\ln xdx=\frac{1}{n^2}$ we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}H_n}{n^2}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx$$

$$=\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{x}dx}_{IBP}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx}_{IBP}$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)}{x}dx+\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{x}dx$$

$$=-\frac34\zeta(3)+\frac12\left(\frac14\zeta(3)\right)=\boxed{-\frac58\zeta(3)}$$

---

**Proof of $\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{x}dx$**:

Proof 1:

Using the algebraic identity

$$b^2=\frac12(a-b)^2+\frac12(a+b)^2-a^2$$

let $a=\ln(1-x)$ and $b=\ln(1+x)$ we have

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{x}\ dx=\frac12\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{x}\ dx}_{\frac{1-x}{1+x}=y}+\frac12\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x^2)}{x}\ dx}_{1-x^2=y}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\ dx}_{1-x=y}\\=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2y}{1-y^2}\ dy+\frac14\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2y}{1-y}\ dy-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2y}{1-y}\ dy\\=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2y}{1+y}\ dy-\frac14\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2y}{1-y}\ dy=\frac12\left(\frac32\zeta(3)\right)-\frac14(2\zeta(3))=\boxed{\frac14\zeta(3)}$$

Proof 2:

Using [the generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3440584)

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^n(1+x)}{x}dx=\frac{\ln^{n+1}(2)}{n+1}+n!\zeta(n+1)+\sum_{k=0}^n k!{n\choose k}\ln^{n-k}(2)\operatorname{Li}_{k+1}\left(\frac12\right)$$

---

**For $A(2,1)$:**

By Cauchy product we have

$$-\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2H_n}{n^2}+\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n}-\frac3{n^3}\right)x^n$$

Set $x=-1$ and rearrange we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(2)}}{n}=3\operatorname{Li}_3(-1)-\ln(2)\operatorname{Li}_2(-1)-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}H_n}{n^2}$$

$$=3\left(-\frac34\zeta(3)\right)-\ln(2)\left(-\frac12\zeta(2)\right)-2\left(-\frac58\zeta(3)\right)=\boxed{\frac12\ln(2)\zeta(2)-\zeta(3)}$$

Answer (score 3):

For convenience define, $$S(m,p)=\sum_{(a,b)\in \mathbb{N^2}}\frac{(-1)^{a+b}}{a^m(a+b)^p}$$

So that,

$$S(m,p)+A(m,p)=\eta(m+p)$$

Where $\eta$ is the dirichlet eta function

Now since, $$\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{a^j(a+b)^{k-j}}=\frac{a}{ba^k}-\frac{a}{b(a+b)^k}-\frac{1}{(a+b)^k}$$

We get the reccurence relation,

$$\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}A(j,k-j)=k\eta(k)-\ln(2)\eta(k-1)-A(1,k-1)$$

From which we get the value of $A(1,1)$

Answer (score 1):

Let us start by noting that the first two sums below are the same (interchange the summation variables and the order of the sums)
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{n(n+m)} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{m(n+m)} = 
\left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \right) \left( \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m} \right). 
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{n(n+m)} = \frac{(\ln(2))^2}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now
\begin{eqnarray*}
A(1,1) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}H_k}{k} &=& \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{n(n+m)} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \zeta_2 - \frac{1}{2} ( \ln(2) )^2.
\end{eqnarray*}

Consider the Harmonic numbers in two ways
\begin{eqnarray*}
H_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}  \frac{1}{k} = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}  \left( \frac{1}{m} -\frac{1}{m+n} \right).
\end{eqnarray*}
We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac{H_k}{k^2} &=& \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}   \frac{1}{m^3} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+m)^2} \\ 
&=&  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nm(n+m)} .
\end{eqnarray*}
As we saw earlier, the first two sums below are the same (interchange the summation variables and the order of the sums)
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+m)^2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m(n+m)^2} = 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nm(n+m)}. 
\end{eqnarray*}
After a little bit of algebra
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nm(n+m)} = 2 \zeta_3 \\ 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+m)^2} = \zeta_3 . \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Next, split the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nm(n+m)}$ according to weather $m>n,m=n$ and $m<n$, this gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nm(n+m)} = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+m)(2n+m)} +\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3}
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+m)(2n+m)} = \frac{3}{4} \zeta_3.
\end{eqnarray*}
Partial fractions ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nm(n+m)}}_{2 \zeta_3} + 
\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+m)(2n+m)}}_{\frac{3}{4} \zeta_3} = 
2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nm(2n+m)}
\end{eqnarray*}
gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nm(2n+m)} = \frac{11}{8} \zeta_3.
\end{eqnarray*}
Partial fractions ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nm(2n+m)}}_{\frac{11}{8} \zeta_3} + 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m(n+m)(2n+m)} = 
\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nm(n+m)}}_{2 \zeta_3}
\end{eqnarray*}
gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m(n+m)(2n+m)} = \frac{5}{8} \zeta_3.
\end{eqnarray*}
Next, consider the sum $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+m)(2n+m)} $ according to weather $m$ is odd or even
\begin{eqnarray*}
\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+m)(2n+m)}}_{ \frac{3}{4} \zeta_3} = 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(2m-1)(2n+2m-1)}+
\frac{1}{2} \underbrace{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+m)(n+2m)}}_{ \frac{5}{8} \zeta_3}
\end{eqnarray*}
so
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(2m-1)(2n+2m-1)}= \frac{7}{16} \zeta_3.
\end{eqnarray*}
Again consider weather $m$ is odd or even
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{n(n+m)(2n+m)} = 
\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(2m-1)(2n+2m-1)}}_{ \frac{7}{16} \zeta_3} -
\frac{1}{2} \underbrace{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+m)(n+2m)}}_{ \frac{5}{8} \zeta_3}
\end{eqnarray*}
so
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{n(n+m)(2n+m)}= \frac{1}{8} \zeta_3.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, split the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{nm(n+m)}$ according to weather $m>n,m=n$ and $m<n$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{nm(n+m)} = -2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{n(n+m)(2n+m)} +\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3}
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{nm(n+m)} = \frac{1}{4} \zeta_3.
\end{eqnarray*}
Again, the first two sums below are equal
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{n(n+m)^2} + 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{m(n+m)^2} = 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{nm(n+m)} 
\end{eqnarray*}
so
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{n(n+m)^2}  = \frac{1}{8} \zeta_3.
\end{eqnarray*}
Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{n^2(n+m)} + 
\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{nm(n+m)}}_{\frac{1}{4} \zeta_3} = 
\underbrace{\left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2} \right) }_{\frac{1}{2} \zeta_2 }
\underbrace{\left( \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m} \right)}_{\ln(2)}. 
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{n^2(n+m)} = \frac{1}{2} \zeta_2 \ln(2) - \frac{1}{4} \zeta_3.
\end{eqnarray*}

So ... finally ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
A(1,2) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}H_k}{k^2} &=& \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^3} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{n(n+m)^2} \\
&=& \frac{5}{8} \zeta_3
\end{eqnarray*}
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
A(2,1) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}H_k^{(2)}}{k} &=& \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^3} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{n^2(n+m)} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \zeta_3 - \frac{1}{2} \zeta_2 \ln(2).
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{l}{I_1} = \int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{x\ln \left( {1 - x} \right)}}{{1 + {x^2}}}\,dx\,\,\,,\,\,\,{I_2} = } \int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{x\ln \left( {1 + x} \right)}}{{1 + {x^2}}}\,dx\,\,\,} \\{I_1}\left( m \right) = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{2x{{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^m}}}{{1 + {x^2}}}dx\,\,\,\,,\,{I_1}^{\rm{\backslash }}\left( {m = 0} \right) = I\,\,\,\,\,,{I_1}\left( m \right) = \left( {\frac{1}{2}{{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^m}\ln \left( {1 + {x^2}} \right)} \right)} _0^1 + \frac{m}{2}\int\limits_0^1 {\ln \left( {1 + {x^2}} \right)} {\left( {1 - x} \right)^{m - 1}}dx\\ =  - \frac{m}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{k}\int\limits_0^1 {{x^{2k}}{{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^{m - 1}}dx = } }  - \frac{m}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{k}\left( {\frac{{\Gamma \left( {2k + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( m \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( {2k + m + 1} \right)}}} \right)} \\\frac{{d{I_1}\left( m \right)}}{{dm}} =  - \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}\Gamma \left( {2k + 1} \right)}}{k}\left( {\frac{{\Gamma \left( {2k + m + 1} \right){\Gamma ^{\rm{\backslash }}}\left( {m + 1} \right) - \Gamma \left( {m + 1} \right){\Gamma ^{\rm{\backslash }}}\left( {2k + m + 1} \right)}}{{{\Gamma ^2}\left( {2k + m + 1} \right)}}} \right)} \end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGceaqabeaacaWGjb
% WaaSbaaSqaaiaaigdaaeqaaOGaeyypa0Zaa8qCaeaadaWcaaqaaiaa
% dIhaciGGSbGaaiOBamaabmaabaGaaGymaiabgkHiTiaadIhaaiaawI
% cacaGLPaaaaeaacaaIXaGaey4kaSIaamiEamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOm
% aaaaaaGccaaMc8UaamizaiaadIhacaaMc8UaaGPaVlaaykW7caGGSa
% GaaGPaVlaaykW7caaMc8UaamysamaaBaaaleaacaaIYaaabeaakiab
% g2da9aWcbaGaaGimaaqaaiaaigdaa0Gaey4kIipakmaapehabaWaaS
% aaaeaacaWG4bGaciiBaiaac6gadaqadaqaaiaaigdacqGHRaWkcaWG
% 4baacaGLOaGaayzkaaaabaGaaGymaiabgUcaRiaadIhadaahaaWcbe
% qaaiaaikdaaaaaaOGaaGPaVlaadsgacaWG4bGaaGPaVlaaykW7caaM
% c8oaleaacaaIWaaabaGaaGymaaqdcqGHRiI8aaGcbaGaamysamaaBa
% aaleaacaaIXaaabeaakmaabmaabaGaamyBaaGaayjkaiaawMcaaiab
% g2da9maalaaabaGaaGymaaqaaiaaikdaaaWaa8qCaeaadaWcaaqaai
% aaikdacaWG4bWaaeWaaeaacaaIXaGaeyOeI0IaamiEaaGaayjkaiaa
% wMcaamaaCaaaleqabaGaamyBaaaaaOqaaiaaigdacqGHRaWkcaWG4b
% WaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaaaakiaadsgacaWG4bGaaGPaVlaaykW7
% caaMc8UaaGPaVlaacYcacaaMc8UaamysamaaBaaaleaacaaIXaaabe
% aakmaaCaaaleqabaGaafixaaaakmaabmaabaGaamyBaiabg2da9iaa
% icdaaiaawIcacaGLPaaacqGH9aqpcaWGjbGaaGPaVlaaykW7caaMc8
% UaaGPaVlaaykW7caGGSaGaamysamaaBaaaleaacaaIXaaabeaakmaa
% bmaabaGaamyBaaGaayjkaiaawMcaaiabg2da9maabmaabaWaaSaaae
% aacaaIXaaabaGaaGOmaaaadaqadaqaaiaaigdacqGHsislcaWG4baa
% caGLOaGaayzkaaWaaWbaaSqabeaacaWGTbaaaOGaciiBaiaac6gada
% qadaqaaiaaigdacqGHRaWkcaWG4bWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaaGc
% caGLOaGaayzkaaaacaGLOaGaayzkaaaaleaacaaIWaaabaGaaGymaa
% qdcqGHRiI8aOWaa0baaSqaaiaaicdaaeaacaaIXaaaaOGaey4kaSYa
% aSaaaeaacaWGTbaabaGaaGOmaaaadaWdXbqaaiGacYgacaGGUbWaae
% WaaeaacaaIXaGaey4kaSIaamiEamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaaaOGa
% ayjkaiaawMcaaaWcbaGaaGimaaqaaiaaigdaa0Gaey4kIipakmaabm
% aabaGaaGymaiabgkHiTiaadIhaaiaawIcacaGLPaaadaahaaWcbeqa
% aiaad2gacqGHsislcaaIXaaaaOGaamizaiaadIhaaeaacqGH9aqpcq
% GHsisldaWcaaqaaiaad2gaaeaacaaIYaaaamaaqahabaWaaSaaaeaa
% daqadaqaaiabgkHiTiaaigdaaiaawIcacaGLPaaadaahaaWcbeqaai
% aadUgaaaaakeaacaWGRbaaamaapehabaGaamiEamaaCaaaleqabaGa
% aGOmaiaadUgaaaGcdaqadaqaaiaaigdacqGHsislcaWG4baacaGLOa
% GaayzkaaWaaWbaaSqabeaacaWGTbGaeyOeI0IaaGymaaaakiaadsga
% caWG4bGaeyypa0daleaacaaIWaaabaGaaGymaaqdcqGHRiI8aaWcba
% Gaam4Aaiabg2da9iaaigdaaeaacqGHEisPa0GaeyyeIuoakiabgkHi
% TmaalaaabaGaamyBaaqaaiaaikdaaaWaaabCaeaadaWcaaqaamaabm
% aabaGaeyOeI0IaaGymaaGaayjkaiaawMcaamaaCaaaleqabaGaam4A
% aaaaaOqaaiaadUgaaaWaaeWaaeaadaWcaaqaaiabfo5ahnaabmaaba
% GaaGOmaiaadUgacqGHRaWkcaaIXaaacaGLOaGaayzkaaGaeu4KdC0a
% aeWaaeaacaWGTbaacaGLOaGaayzkaaaabaGaeu4KdC0aaeWaaeaaca
% aIYaGaam4AaiabgUcaRiaad2gacqGHRaWkcaaIXaaacaGLOaGaayzk
% aaaaaaGaayjkaiaawMcaaaWcbaGaam4Aaiabg2da9iaaigdaaeaacq
% GHEisPa0GaeyyeIuoaaOqaamaalaaabaGaamizaiaadMeadaWgaaWc
% baGaaGymaaqabaGcdaqadaqaaiaad2gaaiaawIcacaGLPaaaaeaaca
% WGKbGaamyBaaaacqGH9aqpcqGHsisldaWcaaqaaiaaigdaaeaacaaI
% YaaaamaaqahabaWaaSaaaeaadaqadaqaaiabgkHiTiaaigdaaiaawI
% cacaGLPaaadaahaaWcbeqaaiaadUgaaaGccqqHtoWrdaqadaqaaiaa
% ikdacaWGRbGaey4kaSIaaGymaaGaayjkaiaawMcaaaqaaiaadUgaaa
% WaaeWaaeaadaWcaaqaaiabfo5ahnaabmaabaGaaGOmaiaadUgacqGH
% RaWkcaWGTbGaey4kaSIaaGymaaGaayjkaiaawMcaaiabfo5ahnaaCa
% aaleqabaGaagixaaaakmaabmaabaGaamyBaiabgUcaRiaaigdaaiaa
% wIcacaGLPaaacqGHsislcqqHtoWrdaqadaqaaiaad2gacqGHRaWkca
% aIXaaacaGLOaGaayzkaaGaeu4KdC0aaWbaaSqabeaacayGCbaaaOWa
% aeWaaeaacaaIYaGaam4AaiabgUcaRiaad2gacqGHRaWkcaaIXaaaca
% GLOaGaayzkaaaabaGaeu4KdC0aaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaOWaaeWa
% aeaacaaIYaGaam4AaiabgUcaRiaad2gacqGHRaWkcaaIXaaacaGLOa
% GaayzkaaaaaaGaayjkaiaawMcaaaWcbaGaam4Aaiabg2da9iaaigda
% aeaacqGHEisPa0GaeyyeIuoaaaaa!54A6!
$$
$$\begin{array}{l}{I_1} = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{k}} \left( {\gamma  + \psi \left( {2k + 1} \right)} \right) = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{k}} {H_{2k}}\\from\,\,\int\limits_0^1 {{x^{k - 1}}\ln \left( {1 - x} \right)\,dx =  - \frac{{{H_k}}}{k}} \\\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{2k}}} {H_{2k}} - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{2k}}} {H_k} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}} \int\limits_0^1 {{x^{2k - 1}}\ln \left( {1 + x} \right)\,dx}  = \int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{x\ln \left( {1 + x} \right)}}{{1 + {x^2}}}\,dx\, = {I_2}\,\,} \\{I_1} + {I_2} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{2k}}} {H_k} \Rightarrow \left( 1 \right)\end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGceaqabeaacaWGjb
% WaaSbaaSqaaiaaigdaaeqaaOGaeyypa0ZaaSaaaeaacaaIXaaabaGa
% aGOmaaaadaaeWbqaamaalaaabaWaaeWaaeaacqGHsislcaaIXaaaca
% GLOaGaayzkaaWaaWbaaSqabeaacaWGRbaaaaGcbaGaam4AaaaaaSqa
% aiaadUgacqGH9aqpcaaIXaaabaGaeyOhIukaniabggHiLdGcdaqada
% qaaiabeo7aNjabgUcaRiabeI8a5naabmaabaGaaGOmaiaadUgacqGH
% RaWkcaaIXaaacaGLOaGaayzkaaaacaGLOaGaayzkaaGaeyypa0ZaaS
% aaaeaacaaIXaaabaGaaGOmaaaadaaeWbqaamaalaaabaWaaeWaaeaa
% cqGHsislcaaIXaaacaGLOaGaayzkaaWaaWbaaSqabeaacaWGRbaaaa
% GcbaGaam4AaaaaaSqaaiaadUgacqGH9aqpcaaIXaaabaGaeyOhIuka
% niabggHiLdGccaWGibWaaSbaaSqaaiaaikdacaWGRbaabeaaaOqaai
% aadAgacaWGYbGaam4Baiaad2gacaaMc8UaaGPaVpaapehabaGaamiE
% amaaCaaaleqabaGaam4AaiabgkHiTiaaigdaaaGcciGGSbGaaiOBam
% aabmaabaGaaGymaiabgkHiTiaadIhaaiaawIcacaGLPaaacaaMc8Ua
% amizaiaadIhacqGH9aqpcqGHsisldaWcaaqaaiaadIeadaWgaaWcba
% Gaam4AaaqabaaakeaacaWGRbaaaaWcbaGaaGimaaqaaiaaigdaa0Ga
% ey4kIipaaOqaamaaqahabaWaaSaaaeaadaqadaqaaiabgkHiTiaaig
% daaiaawIcacaGLPaaadaahaaWcbeqaaiaadUgaaaaakeaacaaIYaGa
% am4AaaaaaSqaaiaadUgacqGH9aqpcaaIXaaabaGaeyOhIukaniabgg
% HiLdGccaWGibWaaSbaaSqaaiaaikdacaWGRbaabeaakiabgkHiTmaa
% qahabaWaaSaaaeaadaqadaqaaiabgkHiTiaaigdaaiaawIcacaGLPa
% aadaahaaWcbeqaaiaadUgaaaaakeaacaaIYaGaam4AaaaaaSqaaiaa
% dUgacqGH9aqpcaaIXaaabaGaeyOhIukaniabggHiLdGccaWGibWaaS
% baaSqaaiaadUgaaeqaaOGaeyypa0ZaaabCaeaadaqadaqaaiabgkHi
% TiaaigdaaiaawIcacaGLPaaadaahaaWcbeqaaiaadUgaaaaabaGaam
% 4Aaiabg2da9iaaigdaaeaacqGHEisPa0GaeyyeIuoakmaapehabaGa
% aiiEamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaiaadUgacqGHsislcaaIXaaaaOGaci
% iBaiaac6gadaqadaqaaiaaigdacqGHRaWkcaWG4baacaGLOaGaayzk
% aaGaaGPaVlaadsgacaWG4baaleaacaaIWaaabaGaaGymaaqdcqGHRi
% I8aOGaeyypa0Zaa8qCaeaadaWcaaqaaiaadIhaciGGSbGaaiOBamaa
% bmaabaGaaGymaiabgUcaRiaadIhaaiaawIcacaGLPaaaaeaacaaIXa
% Gaey4kaSIaamiEamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaaaaGccaaMc8Uaamiz
% aiaadIhacaaMc8Uaeyypa0JaamysamaaBaaaleaacaaIYaaabeaaki
% aaykW7caaMc8oaleaacaaIWaaabaGaaGymaaqdcqGHRiI8aaGcbaGa
% amysamaaBaaaleaacaaIXaaabeaakiabgUcaRiaadMeadaWgaaWcba
% GaaGOmaaqabaGccqGH9aqpdaaeWbqaamaalaaabaWaaeWaaeaacqGH
% sislcaaIXaaacaGLOaGaayzkaaWaaWbaaSqabeaacaWGRbaaaaGcba
% GaaGOmaiaadUgaaaaaleaacaWGRbGaeyypa0JaaGymaaqaaiabg6Hi
% LcqdcqGHris5aOGaamisamaaBaaaleaacaWGRbaabeaakiabgkDiEp
% aabmaabaGaaGymaaGaayjkaiaawMcaaaaaaa!EDD5!
$$
$$\begin{array}{l}{I_1} + {I_2} = \int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{x\ln \left( {1 - {x^2}} \right)}}{{1 + {x^2}}}\,dx\,\,\,}  = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{\ln \left( {1 - x} \right)}}{{1 + x}}\,dx\,\,\,} \\by\,\,\,using\,\,the\,\,x = \frac{{1 - y}}{{1 + y}}\,\,\,\,\\\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{2k}}} {H_k} = {I_1} + {I_2} = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{\ln \left( {\frac{{2y}}{{1 + y}}} \right)}}{{1 + y}}\,dy = \frac{1}{4}{{\ln }^2}2 - \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{{24}}} \\and\,\,then\,\,we\,\,obtain\,\,the\,\,needed\,\,proof\end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGceaqabeaacaWGjb
% WaaSbaaSqaaiaaigdaaeqaaOGaey4kaSIaamysamaaBaaaleaacaaI
% Yaaabeaakiabg2da9maapehabaWaaSaaaeaacaWG4bGaciiBaiaac6
% gadaqadaqaaiaaigdacqGHsislcaWG4bWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaa
% aaGccaGLOaGaayzkaaaabaGaaGymaiabgUcaRiaadIhadaahaaWcbe
% qaaiaaikdaaaaaaOGaaGPaVlaadsgacaWG4bGaaGPaVlaaykW7caaM
% c8oaleaacaaIWaaabaGaaGymaaqdcqGHRiI8aOGaeyypa0ZaaSaaae
% aacaaIXaaabaGaaGOmaaaadaWdXbqaamaalaaabaGaciiBaiaac6ga
% daqadaqaaiaaigdacqGHsislcaWG4baacaGLOaGaayzkaaaabaGaaG
% ymaiabgUcaRiaadIhaaaGaaGPaVlaadsgacaWG4bGaaGPaVlaaykW7
% caaMc8oaleaacaaIWaaabaGaaGymaaqdcqGHRiI8aaGcbaGaamOyai
% aadMhacaaMc8UaaGPaVlaaykW7caWG1bGaam4CaiaadMgacaWGUbGa
% am4zaiaaykW7caaMc8UaamiDaiaadIgacaWGLbGaaGPaVlaaykW7ca
% WG4bGaeyypa0ZaaSaaaeaacaaIXaGaeyOeI0IaamyEaaqaaiaaigda
% cqGHRaWkcaWG5baaaiaaykW7caaMc8UaaGPaVlaaykW7aeaadaaeWb
% qaamaalaaabaWaaeWaaeaacqGHsislcaaIXaaacaGLOaGaayzkaaWa
% aWbaaSqabeaacaWGRbaaaaGcbaGaaGOmaiaadUgaaaaaleaacaWGRb
% Gaeyypa0JaaGymaaqaaiabg6HiLcqdcqGHris5aOGaamisamaaBaaa
% leaacaWGRbaabeaakiabg2da9iaadMeadaWgaaWcbaGaaGymaaqaba
% GccqGHRaWkcaWGjbWaaSbaaSqaaiaaikdaaeqaaOGaeyypa0ZaaSaa
% aeaacaaIXaaabaGaaGOmaaaadaWdXbqaamaalaaabaGaciiBaiaac6
% gadaqadaqaamaalaaabaGaaGOmaiaadMhaaeaacaaIXaGaey4kaSIa
% amyEaaaaaiaawIcacaGLPaaaaeaacaaIXaGaey4kaSIaamyEaaaaca
% aMc8UaamizaiaadMhacqGH9aqpdaWcaaqaaiaaigdaaeaacaaI0aaa
% aiGacYgacaGGUbWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaOGaaGOmaiabgkHiTm
% aalaaabaGaeqiWda3aaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaaGcbaGaaGOmaiaa
% isdaaaaaleaacaaIWaaabaGaaGymaaqdcqGHRiI8aaGcbaGaamyyai
% aad6gacaWGKbGaaGPaVlaaykW7caWG0bGaamiAaiaadwgacaWGUbGa
% aGPaVlaaykW7caWG3bGaamyzaiaaykW7caaMc8Uaam4Baiaadkgaca
% WG0bGaamyyaiaadMgacaWGUbGaaGPaVlaaykW7caWG0bGaamiAaiaa
% dwgacaaMc8UaaGPaVlaad6gacaWGLbGaamyzaiaadsgacaWGLbGaam
% izaiaaykW7caaMc8UaamiCaiaadkhacaWGVbGaam4BaiaadAgaaaaa
% !ED28!
$$
by   Mr. Sherif Hamed

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of Kouba's https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.1842 equation
$$\sum_{n\ge 1}(-)^{n-1}\frac{H_{kn}}{n}
=
\frac{(k^2+1)\pi^2}{24k}-\frac12 \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\log^2\left(2\sin\frac{(2j+1)\pi}{2k}\right)
$$