# Evaluation of $\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1+x)}{x} \ dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers

One of the ways to approach it lies in the area of the dilogarithm, but is it possible to evaluate it
by other means of the **real analysis** (without using dilogarithm)?

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1+x)}{x} \ dx$$

**EDIT**: maybe you're aware of some easy way to do that. I'd appreciate it!
Some words on the generalization case (by means of the **real analysis** again)?

$$F(n)=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^n(1+x)}{x} \ dx, \space n\in \mathbb{N}$$

Comment: do you need a closed form? Otherwise $\log(1+x) \sim x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3}$ is a good approximation

Comment: Yes, I need closed forms.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha thinks the first two answers (for $n=1$ and $n=2$) are ${1\over2}\zeta(2)$ and ${1\over4}\zeta(3)$.  After that it gets dilogarithmically messy.

Comment: An antiderivative of $\frac{\log^{n}(1+x)}{x}$ in terms of polylogarithms can found by repeatedly integrating by parts.  And if you're interested, joriki evaluated the case $n=2$ using contour integration. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316745/how-to-evaluate-displaystyle-int-01-frac-log21xx-mathrm-dx

Comment: @RandomVariable Yes, indeed (I missed a tricky series while doing things in a hurry).

Comment: @RandomVariable It's a dream to evaluate that integral in an elementary way (maybe one I desire too much).

Comment: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290250/show-that-int-0-pi-2-frac-log2-sin-x-log2-cos-x-cos-x-sin-x-mathrm/291975#291975) are useful techniques.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Squaring the series for $\log(1+x)$ yields
$$
\log(1+x)^2=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^kx^k}{j(k-j)}
$$
Dividing by $x$ and integrating gives
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x)^2}{x}\mathrm{d}x
&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{jk(k-j)}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=j+1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{jk(k-j)}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j+k}}{jk(j+k)}\\[9pt]
&=\frac{\zeta(3)}{4}
\end{align}
$$
Using $(5)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/499716):
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}H_n
=-\frac34\zeta(3)+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{(n+k)kn}
$$
and $(6)$ from the same answer:
$$
-\frac58\zeta(3)
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}H_n
$$
we get
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j+k}}{jk(j+k)}
=\frac{\zeta(3)}{4}
$$

Comment: Thanks, that's the way. (+1)

Answer (score 9):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 + x} \over x}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 + x} \over x}\,\dd x}
> =\int_{1}^{2}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x - 1}\,\dd x
> =\int_{1}^{1/2}{\ln^{2}\pars{1/x} \over 1/x - 1}\,\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}
> =\int_{1/2}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x\pars{1 - x}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{1/2}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
> + \int_{1/2}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
> ={1 \over 3}\,\ln^{3}\pars{2}
> +\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\color{#00f}{\int_{1/2}^{1}\ln^{2}\pars{x}x^{n - 1}\,\dd x}
> \qquad\qquad\pars{1}
> \end{align}

$$
\color{#00f}{\int_{1/2}^{1}\ln^{2}\pars{x}x^{n - 1}\,\dd x}
=\lim_{\mu\ \to\ n - 1}\partiald[2]{}{\mu}\int_{1/2}^{1}x^{\mu}\,\dd x
=\lim_{\mu\ \to\ n - 1}\partiald[2]{}{\mu}
\bracks{{1 - \pars{1/2}^{\mu + 1} \over \mu + 1}}
$$

> $$
> \color{#00f}{\int_{1/2}^{1}\ln^{2}\pars{x}x^{n - 1}\,\dd x}
> =-2\,{\pars{1/2}^{n} \over n^{3}}+ {2 \over n^{3}}
> -\ln^{2}\pars{2}\,{\pars{1/2}^{n} \over n}
> -2\ln\pars{2}\,{\pars{1/2}^{n} \over n^{2}}
> $$

By replacing in $\pars{1}$:
\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 + x} \over x}\,\dd x}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 3}\,\ln^{3}\pars{2} -2{\rm Li}_{3}\pars{\half}
+2\zeta\pars{3} - \ln^{2}\pars{2}{\rm Li}_{1}\pars{\half}
-2\ln\pars{2}{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\half}\tag{2}
\end{align}

> You'll find values for the *PolyLogarithm Function*
>   $\ds{{\rm Li}_{s}\pars{\half}\,,\ \pars{~s = 1,2,3~}\,,\ }$ in
>   [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm):
>   \begin{align}
> {\rm Li}_{1}\pars{\half} &= \ln\pars{2}
> \\[3mm]
> {\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\half} &= {\pi^{2} \over 12} - \half\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}
> \\[3mm]
> {\rm Li}_{3}\pars{\half} &= {1 \over 6}\,\ln^{3}\pars{2}- {\pi^{2} \over 12}\,\ln\pars{2}
> +{7 \over 8}\,\zeta\pars{3}
> \end{align}

With these identities and result $\pars{2}$:
\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 + x} \over x}\,\dd x}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{{1 \over 3}\,\ln^{3}\pars{2}} +\
\overbrace{\bracks{\color{#00f}{-\,{1 \over 3}\,\ln^{3}\pars{2}}
+
\color{magenta}{{\pi^{2} \over 6}\,\ln\pars{2}}
{\large -{7 \over 4}\,\zeta\pars{3}}}}^{\ds{-2{\rm Li}_{3}\pars{\half}}}\
+\ {\large 2\zeta\pars{3}}
\\[3mm]&+\
\underbrace{\bracks{\color{#990099}{-\ln^{3}\pars{2}}}}
_{\ds{-\ln^{2}\pars{2}{\rm Li}_{1}\pars{\half}}}\ +\
\underbrace{\bracks{\color{magenta}{-\,{\pi^{2} \over 6}\,\ln\pars{2}}
+\color{#990099}{\ln^{3}\pars{2}}}}_{\ds{-2\ln\pars{2}{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\half}}}\
=\ \pars{2 - {7 \over 4}}\zeta\pars{3}
\end{align}

> $$
> \color{#66f}{\large%
> \int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 + x} \over x}\,\dd x = {\zeta\pars{3} \over 4}}
> \approx 0.3005
> $$

Comment: Good job there! :-) (+1)

Answer (score 5):

You can find a nice generalization for $\int_0^1\frac{\ln^n(1+x)}{x}dx$ in lemma $2.2$ in [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.12113.pdf) and I am going to type it here with little more details.

Start with subbing $\frac{1}{1+x}=y$

$$I_n=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^n(1+x)}{x}dx=(-1)^n\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\ln^n(y)}{y(1-y)}dy$$

$$=(-1)^n\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\ln^n(y)}{y}dy+(-1)^n\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\ln^n(y)}{1-y}dy$$

$$=(-1)^n\left[(-1)^n\frac{\ln^{n+1}(2)}{n+1}\right]+(-1)^n\int_{0}^1\frac{\ln^n(y)}{1-y}dy-(-1)^n\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\ln^n(y)}{1-y}dy$$

$$=(-1)^n\left[(-1)^n\frac{\ln^{n+1}(2)}{n+1}\right]+(-1)^n\left[(-1)^n n!\zeta(n+1)\right]-(-1)^n\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\ln^n(y)}{1-y}dy$$

$$=\frac{\ln^{n+1}(2)}{n+1}+n!\zeta(n+1)-(-1)^n\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\ln^n(y)}{1-y}dy\tag1$$

By using the binomial theorem

$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^{n-k}y^k$$

we get

$$\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\ln^n(y)}{1-y}dy\overset{2y=x}{=}\int_0^1\frac{(\ln(x)-\ln(2))^n}{2-x}dx$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}(-\ln(2))^{n-k}\left(\int_0^1\frac{\ln^k(x)}{2-x}dx\right)$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}(-\ln(2))^{n-k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac1{2^i} \int_0^1 x^{i-1}\ln^k(x)dx\right)$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}(-\ln(2))^{n-k}\left((-1)^k k!\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac1{2^i i^{k+1}}\right)$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}(-\ln(2))^{n-k}(-1)^k k!\operatorname{Li}_{k+1}\left(\frac12\right)\tag3$$

Plug $(3)$ in $(1)$ we get

> $$I_n=\frac{\ln^{n+1}(2)}{n+1}+n!\zeta(n+1)-\sum_{k=0}^n k!{n\choose k}\ln^{n-k}(2)\operatorname{Li}_{k+1}\left(\frac12\right)$$
> or
> $$(-1)^n\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\ln^n(y)}{y(1-y)}dy=\frac{\ln^{n+1}(2)}{n+1}+n!\zeta(n+1)-\sum_{k=0}^n k!{n\choose k}\ln^{n-k}(2)\operatorname{Li}_{k+1}\left(\frac12\right)$$

Comment: Wonderful solution!

Comment: Should the final answer be $I_n=\frac{\ln^{n+1}(2)}{n+1}+n!\zeta(n+1)-\sum_{k=0}^n k!{n\choose k}\ln^{n-k}(2)\operatorname{Li}_{k+1}\left(\frac12\right)?$

Comment: Since $\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\ln^n(y)}{1-y}dy\overset{2y=x}{=}\int_0^1\frac{(\ln(x)-\ln(2))^n}{2-x}dx.$

Comment: Thank you @Lai I fixed it

Comment: Ali, thank you for helping me to solve the integral $\int_0^1 \int_0^1\left(\frac{\ln (1+x y)}{(1+x y)}\right)^3 d x d y$

Answer (score 4):

The following new solution to the classical harmonic series result, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n}{n^2}=\frac{5}{8}\zeta(3)$, is proposed by **Cornel Ioan Valean**, using the powerful identity,
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2k(2k+2n-1)}=\frac{1}{2(2n-1)}\left(2H_{2n}-H_n-2\log(2)\right),\tag1$$  found and proved in $(6.289)$ in the book ***(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series***.

If we multiply both sides of $(1)$ by $1/(2n-1)$, consider the sum from $n=1$ to $\infty$ and then reindex, we have for the right-hand side that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{2n}}{(2n-1)^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n}{(2n-1)^2}-\log(2)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}$$
$$=-\frac{3}{4}\log(2)\zeta(2)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{2n-1}}{(2n-1)^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n}{(2n+1)^2}$$
$$=-\frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n}{n^2}=\frac{1}{8}\zeta(3)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n}{n^2}.\tag2$$

On the other hand, based on $(1)$, we have for the left-hand side that
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2k(2k+2n-1)(2n-1)}\right)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2k(2k+2n-1)(2n-1)}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{2n-1}=\frac{1}{4}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\left(H_{2k}-\frac{1}{2}H_k\right)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{2k}}{(2k)^2}-\frac{1}{8}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_k}{k^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{2n-1}=\frac{1}{4}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\left(H_{2k}-\frac{1}{2}H_k\right)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{2k}}{(2k)^2}-\frac{1}{8}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_k}{k^2}$$
$$=\frac{3}{8}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_k}{k^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{H_k}{k^2}=\frac{3}{4}\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{2}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n}{n^2}.\tag3$$

By combining $(2)$ and $(3)$, we obtain that

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n}{n^2}=\frac{5}{8}\zeta(3).$$

In the calculations we needed particular cases of the generalizations,
\begin{equation*}
2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{H_k}{k^n}=(n+2)\zeta(n+1)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-2} \zeta(n-k) \zeta(k+1), \  n\ge2,
\end{equation*}
and 
\begin{equation*}
\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_k}{(2k+1)^{2m}}=2m\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2m+1}}\right)\zeta(2m+1)-2\log(2)\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2m}}\right)\zeta(2m)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
-\frac{1}{2^{2m}}\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}(1-2^{i+1})(1-2^{2m-i})\zeta(1+i)\zeta(2m-i),
\end{equation*}
proved in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3268851. Cornel's solution to the case, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n}{n^4}=\frac{59}{32}\zeta(5)-\frac{1}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$, may be found in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3269815, and the present technique may be easily extended to calculate the generalization, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \frac{H_n}{n^{2m}}$.

Since the given integral easily reduces to the calculations of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n}{n^2}$, the solution is finalized.

Answer (score 3):

**Different approach**:

We have

$$\ln^2(1+x)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n+1}(-x)^{n+1}$$

Divide by $x$ then integrate to get

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{x}\ dx&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_n}{n+1}\int_0^1x^n\ dx\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_n}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}H_{n-1}}{n^2}\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}H_n}{n^2}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^3}\\
&=2\left(-\frac58\zeta(3)\right)-2\operatorname{Li}_3(-1)\\
&=-\frac54\zeta(3)-2\left(-\frac34\zeta(3)\right)\\
&=\boxed{\frac14\zeta(3)}
\end{align}

---

**Note:**

We have [the generating identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366039/a-group-of-important-generating-functions-involving-harmonic-number)

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\frac{H_n}{n^2}=\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)+\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)+\frac12\ln x\ln^2(1-x)+\zeta(3)$$

and by setting $x=-1$ and considering only the real parts we have

$$\Re\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{H_n}{n^2}=\operatorname{Li}_3(-1)-\Re\operatorname{Li}_3(2)+\Re\ln2\operatorname{Li}_2(2)+\frac12\underbrace{\Re\ln(-1)\ln^22}_{0}+\zeta(3)\tag{1}$$

Using the trilogarithmic identity

$$\operatorname{Li}_3(x)+\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)+\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)=\frac16\ln^3x+\zeta(2)\ln x-\frac12\ln^2x\ln(1-x)+\zeta(3)$$

set $x=-1$ and take the real parts to have

$$ \boxed{\Re\operatorname{Li}_3(2)=\frac78\zeta(3)+\frac32\ln2\zeta(2)}$$

also Landen's identity gives

$$ \boxed{\Re\operatorname{Li}_2(2)=\frac32\zeta(2)}$$

Plugging the boxed results along with $\operatorname{Li}_3(-1)=-\frac34\zeta(3)$ in (1) we have

> $$\Re\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_n}{n^2}=-\frac58\zeta(3)$$

Answer (score 2):

On the path of Felix Marin,
\begin{align}J&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)^2}{x}\\
&\overset{y=\frac{1}{1+x}}=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{x(1-x)}\,dx\\
&=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{x}\,dx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\left(\ln^3 (1)-\ln^3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx-\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\ln^3 2+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx-\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
&\overset{y=\frac{x}{1-x},\text{the 2nd integral}}=\frac{1}{3}\ln^3 2+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\ln^3 2+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x}\,dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 (1+x)}{1+x}\,dx+2\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)\ln x}{1+x}\,dx\\
&\overset{IBP}=\frac{1}{3}\ln^3 2+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x}\,dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 (1+x)}{1+x}\,dx-J\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\ln^3 2+\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx-\frac{1}{3}\ln^3 2-J\\
&\overset{y=x^2}=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx-J\\
J&=\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{8}\times 2\zeta(3)\\
&=\boxed{\frac{1}{4}\zeta(3)}
\end{align}
NB: i assume that, \begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx=2\zeta(3)\end{align}
(proof: Taylor expansion)

Answer (score 1):

Using the algebraic identity

$$b^2=\frac12(a-b)^2+\frac12(a+b)^2-a^2$$

let $a=\ln(1-x)$ and $b=\ln(1+x)$ we have

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{x}\ dx=\frac12\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{x}\ dx}_{\frac{1-x}{1+x}=y}+\frac12\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x^2)}{x}\ dx}_{1-x^2=y}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\ dx}_{1-x=y}\\=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2y}{1-y^2}\ dy+\frac14\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2y}{1-y}\ dy-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2y}{1-y}\ dy\\=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2y}{1+y}\ dy-\frac14\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2y}{1-y}\ dy=\frac12\left(\frac32\zeta(3)\right)-\frac14(2\zeta(3))=\boxed{\frac14\zeta(3)}$$

Comment: For the last approach see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2143161/186817

Comment: Yes same idea. Using algebraic identity for logarithmic integrals is very common technique.

Comment: The proof of Felix Marin can be much more shorter.

Comment: yes but there you need to use the special values of $\operatorname{Li}_2(1/2)$ and $\operatorname{Li}_3(1/2)$ which is not a big deal.

Comment: Maybe using not directly such values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution by finding the closed form of $\int \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx$ then letting $x\mapsto -x$:

$$\int \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx=\int \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1-x)}{x}dx\overset{IBP}{=}-\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\ln(1-x)-\int\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1-x}dx$$

For the last integral, set $1-x=y$ then use the reflection formula:
$$\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)=\zeta(2)-\ln(y)\ln(1-y)-\operatorname{Li}_2(y)$$

We obtain that

$$\int\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1-x}dx=-\int\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)}{y}dy$$

$$=-\zeta(2)\int\frac{dy}y+\int\frac{\ln(y)\ln(1-y)}{y}dy+\int\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(y)}{y}dy$$

$$=-\zeta(2)\ln(y)+\left[-\operatorname{Li}_2(y)\ln(y)+\int\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(y)}{y}dy\right]+\int\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(y)}{y}dy$$

$$=-\zeta(2)\ln(y)-\operatorname{Li}_2(y)\ln(y)+2\operatorname{Li}_3(y)$$

$$=-\zeta(2)\ln(1-x)-\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)\ln(1-x)+2\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)$$

Then

$$\int\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx=\ln(1-x)\left[\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)-\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\zeta(2)\right]-2\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)$$

Now consider the integral boundaries $(0,a)$,

$$\int_0^a\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx=\ln(1-a)\left[\operatorname{Li}_2(1-a)-\operatorname{Li}_2(a)+\zeta(2)\right]-2\operatorname{Li}_3(1-a)+2\zeta(3)$$

Therefore

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{x}dx\overset{x\mapsto -x}{=}\int_0^{-1}\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx$$

$$=\ln(2)\left[\operatorname{Li}_2(2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(-1)+\zeta(2)\right]-2\operatorname{Li}_3(2)+2\zeta(3)$$

substitute $\Re\operatorname{Li}_2(2)=\frac32\zeta(2)$ and $\Re\operatorname{Li}_3(2)=\frac78\zeta(3)+\frac32\ln2\zeta(2)$, the closed form follows.