# Closed- form of $\int_0^1 \frac{{\text{Li}}_3^2(-x)}{x^2}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, polylogarithm

Is there a possibility to find a closed-form for
 $$\int_0^1 \frac{{\text{Li}}_3^2(-x)}{x^2}\,dx$$

Comment: Try integration by parts, differentiating the polylog part. For instance, first step would give you ${\rm L}_2(-x){\rm L}_3(-x)/x^2$ and then you can differentiate further to get down to lower and lower polylog terms. This is nice because the form of the integral is preserved, only the subscripts are getting smaller.

Answer (score 13):

$\def\Li{{\rm Li}}$
Repeatedly integrate by parts.
\begin{align}
&\int^1_0\frac{\Li_3^2(-x)}{x^2}{\rm d}x\\
=&-\frac{\Li_3^2(-x)}{x}\Bigg{|}^1_0+\int^1_0\frac{2\Li_2(-x)\Li_3(-x)}{x^2}{\rm d}x\\
=&-\frac{9}{16}\zeta^2(3)-\frac{2\Li_2(-x)\Li_3(-x)}{x}\Bigg{|}^1_0+\int^1_0\frac{2\Li_2^2(-x)}{x^2}{\rm d}x-\int^1_0\frac{2\Li_3(-x)\ln(1+x)}{x^2}{\rm d}x\\
=&-\frac{9}{16}\zeta^2(3)-\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{2\Li_2^2(-x)}{x}\Bigg{|}^1_0-\int^1_0\frac{4\Li_2(-x)\ln(1+x)}{x^2}{\rm d}x\\
&+\frac{2\Li_3(-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}\Bigg{|}^1_0-\int^1_0\frac{2\Li_3(-x)}{x(1+x)}{\rm d}x-\int^1_0\frac{2\Li_2(-x)\ln(1+x)}{x^2}{\rm d}x\\
=&-\frac{9}{16}\zeta^2(3)-\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{2}\zeta^2(2)+\frac{7}{4}\zeta(4)-\frac{3}{2}\zeta(3)\ln{2}+\int^1_0\frac{2\Li_3(-x)}{1+x}{\rm d}x\\
&+\frac{6\Li_2(-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}\Bigg{|}^1_0-\int^1_0\frac{6\Li_2(-x)}{x(1+x)}{\rm d}x+\int^1_0\frac{6\ln^2(1+x)}{x^2}{\rm d}x\\
=&-\frac{9}{16}\zeta^2(3)-\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{2}\zeta^2(2)+\frac{7}{4}\zeta(4)-\frac{3}{2}\zeta(3)\ln{2}+\frac{9}{2}\zeta(3)-3\zeta(2)\ln{2}\\
&+\int^1_0\frac{6\Li_2(-x)}{1+x}{\rm d}x+\int^1_0\frac{2\Li_3(-x)}{1+x}{\rm d}x-\frac{6\ln^2(1+x)}{x}\Bigg{|}^1_0+\int^1_0\frac{12\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}{\rm d}x\\
=&-\frac{9}{16}\zeta^2(3)-\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{2}\zeta^2(2)+\frac{7}{4}\zeta(4)-\frac{3}{2}\zeta(3)\ln{2}+\frac{9}{2}\zeta(3)-3\zeta(2)\ln{2}\\
&+6\zeta(2)-12\ln^2{2}+\int^1_0\frac{6\Li_2(-x)}{1+x}{\rm d}x+\int^1_0\frac{2\Li_3(-x)}{1+x}{\rm d}x
\end{align}
Since
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\frac{6\Li_2(-x)}{1+x}{\rm d}x
=&6\Li_2(-x)\ln(1+x)\Bigg{|}^1_0+\int^1_0\frac{6\ln^2(1+x)}{x}{\rm d}x\\
=&\frac{3}{2}\zeta(3)-3\zeta(2)\ln{2}
\end{align}
(see [Log Integrals I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967189/log-integrals-i?lq=1))

and
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\frac{2\Li_3(-x)}{1+x}{\rm d}x
=&2\Li_3(-x)\ln(1+x)\Bigg{|}^1_0-\int^1_0\underbrace{\frac{2\Li_2(-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}{\rm d}x}_{\displaystyle\small{2\Li_2(-x)\ {\rm d}\Li_2(-x)}}\\
=&\frac{1}{4}\zeta^2(2)-\frac{3}{2}\zeta(3)\ln{2}
\end{align}
The closed form is
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\frac{\Li_3^2(-x)}{x^2}{\rm d}x
=&-\frac{9}{16}\zeta^2(3)-\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{4}\zeta^2(2)+\frac{7}{4}\zeta(4)-3\zeta(3)\ln{2}\\&+6\zeta(3)-6\zeta(2)\ln{2}+6\zeta(2)-12\ln^2{2}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Focus on the relation
$$\frac{d}{dx}{\rm Li}_k(x)=\frac{1}{x}{\rm Li}_{k-1}(x)$$

Let's look at the derivative of ${\rm Li}_m {\rm Li}_n$ in general:
$$\frac{d}{dx}({\rm Li}_m(-x){\rm Li}_n(-x))=\frac{1}{x}({\rm Li}_{m-1}(-x){\rm Li}_n(-x)+{\rm Li}_m(-x){\rm Li}_{n-1}(-x))$$

Let's define
$$f(m,n)=\int_0^1 \frac{{\rm Li}_m(-x){\rm Li}_n(-x)}{x^2}dx$$
Integration by parts:
$$f(m,n)=-\frac{1}{x}{\rm Li}_m(-x){\rm Li}_n(-x)|_0^1 +\int_0^1 \frac{{\rm Li}_{m-1}(-x){\rm Li}_n(-x)+{\rm Li}_{m}(-x){\rm Li}_{n-1}(-x)}{x^2}dx$$
$$f(m,n)=-\frac{1}{x}{\rm Li}_m(-x){\rm Li}_n(-x)|_0^1 +f(m-1,n)+f(m,n-1)$$
This is a recursive relation that can express $f(3,3)$ with lower terms that are easier to express analytically. Note that the nonintegral part above has to be taken as a limit at $x=0$. You can imagine having $\epsilon$ for the lower integral bound and taking $\epsilon\to 0$ at the end.

Anyway, you can see from the power series definition that
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}{\rm Li}_m(\epsilon){\rm Li}_n(\epsilon)=0$$
Additionally, ${\rm Li}_n(-1)=-\eta(n)$ where $\eta$ is the Dirichlet eta function. Simplification:
$$f(m,n)=-\eta(m)\eta(n) +f(m-1,n)+f(m,n-1)$$

First of all, $f$ is symmetric in the arguments. Secondly, ${\rm Li}_0(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}$ so recursion can end at
$$f(n,0)=-\int_0^1 \frac{{\rm Li}_n(-x)}{x(1+x)}dx=-\int_0^1 \frac{{\rm Li}_n(-x)}{x}dx+\int_0^1 \frac{{\rm Li}_n(-x)}{1+x}dx=$$
$$=-{\rm Li}_{n+1}(-1)+\int_0^1 \frac{{\rm Li}_n(-x)}{1+x}dx$$
The first one is again the eta function. But the second one I don't know what to do with. Maybe this wasn't such a good idea. Any suggestions?