# How find this integral $I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{(1+xy)}}{1-xy}dxdy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

> Find this integral
>
> $$I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\ln{(1+xy)}}{1-xy}dxdy$$

My try: since
$$\dfrac{1}{1-xy}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(xy)^n$$
so
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}y^n\int_{0}^{1}x^n\ln{(1+xy)}dx$$
because
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^n\ln{(1+xy)}dx=\dfrac{x^{n+1}\ln{(1+xy)}}{n+1}|_{0}^{1}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^{n+1}y}{1+xy}dx=\dfrac{\ln{(1+y)}}{n+1}-I_{1}$$
where
$$I_{1}=y\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{1+xy}dx$$  even if $I_{1}$ can use the beta function,
But  then  follow I can't it.Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

> $$
> \int_{0}^{1}\!\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\ln{(1+xy)}}{1-xy}\mathrm dx \: \mathrm dy = \frac{\pi^2}{4}\ln 2 -\zeta(3). \tag1
> $$

To obtain $(1)$ one may write
$$
\begin{align}
I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\ln{(1+xy)}}{1-xy}dxdy &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\dfrac{(xy)^n}{1-xy}dxdy \\
& =
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{(xy)^n}{1-xy}dxdy \\
& =
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\Phi(1,2,n+1)\\
& =
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2} -\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}  \right)\\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6} \quad -\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}\,\right) \\
& = \frac{\pi^2}{4}\ln 2 -\zeta(3)
\end{align}
$$ where we have used a result on double integrals from [J. Guillera and J. Sondow](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0506319.pdf) (30): 
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{(xy)^{u-1}}{1-xyz}(-\ln(xy))^s dxdy =\Gamma(s+2)\Phi(z,s+2,u)
$$ $\displaystyle \Phi$ denoting the Lerch transcendent function: $$ \Phi(z,s,u)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{(k+u)^{s}}.$$

Update: a proof of the last step may be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275643/proving-an-alternating-euler-sum-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k1-h-kk/610151#610151).

Comment: edit the summation over $n$. The sums start at $n=1$

Comment: @Leucippus Edited. Thanks!

Comment: @OlivierOloa Mister Oloa, how did you compute $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6} \quad -\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}\,\right)$? It seems to me this is an important step that was skipped.

Comment: @Chris'ssis You are right, I had used a special value of a standard integral I knew. Please, see the edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Though I'd actually prefer the solutions other users have already posted to the solution below, I thought it worth pointing out that there's really nothing stopping you from solving this integral by brute force.

The main non-trivial fact needed beforehand is the anti-derivative,

$$\int\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\ln{(1+u)}}{1-u}=-\operatorname{Li}_2{\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)}\ln{(1+x)}+constant,$$

which can be verified via differentiation.

Here's a sketch of the rest of the calculation:

$$\begin{align}
I
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{(1+xy)}}{1-xy}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\ln{(1+u)}}{1-u}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x}\left[-\operatorname{Li}_2{\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)}\ln{(1+x)}-\frac12\ln^2{2}+\frac12\zeta{(2)}\right]\\
&=-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)}\ln{(1+x)}}{x}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\zeta{(2)}-\ln^2{2}-2\operatorname{Li}_2{\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)}}{2x}\\
&=\frac58 \zeta{(3)}+\frac12\zeta{(2)}\ln{2}-\frac{13}{8}\zeta{(3)}+\zeta{(2)}\ln{2}\\
&=\frac32\zeta{(2)}\ln{2}-\zeta{(3)}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I use Feynman's way by setting
$$
\mathcal{I}(\alpha)=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+\alpha xy)}{1-xy}\ dx\ dy
$$
then
\begin{align}
\frac{d\mathcal{I}}{d\alpha}
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1+\alpha xy)(1-xy)}\ dx\ dy\\
&=\frac1{1+\alpha}\int_0^1\int_0^1\left[\frac{1}{1-xy}+\frac\alpha{1+\alpha xy}\right]\ dx\ dy\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\cdot\frac1{1+\alpha}+\frac{\text{Li}_2(-\alpha)}{\alpha} + \frac{\text{Li}_2(-\alpha)}{1+\alpha},
\end{align}
but I'm having trouble to evaluate the last term. Any idea?

Comment: @Tunk-Fey I'm sorry, I'm not sure what exactly you're referring to. Are you asking how to evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\text{Li}_2(-\alpha)}{1+\alpha}\mathrm{d}\alpha$? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Notice that in this and other similar contexts, $\ln2$ acts as a “normalized” value for $\zeta(1)$, since we are expecting results of the form $\displaystyle\sum a_k\cdot\zeta(k)\cdot\zeta(n-k)$, with $a_k\in\mathbb A$. However, in **other** contexts, it is $\gamma$ that fulfills this requirement, since $\dfrac{\zeta(1^+)+\zeta(1^-)}2=\gamma$.

Comment: David: Yes, I'm looking a way to evaluate that integral. If possible, the indefinite integral. @Lucian I don't understand your comment, could you be more specific? Anyway, I found the source to evaluate the integral but it's too complicated to me. Perhaps, you both have a simple one.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey I think the best way would be to use the two-dilog functional identity $\frac{\text{Li}_2{(-z)}}{1+z}=\frac{\zeta{(2)}-\ln{(-z)}\ln{(1+z)-\operatorname{Li}_2{(1+z)}}}{1+z}$ to split up the integrand into three bite-size morsels. None of the resulting integrals seem too difficult after that.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey
$$
\int_{0}^{1}{{\rm Li}_{2}\left(-\alpha\right) \over 1 + \alpha}\,{\rm d}\alpha
=-\int_{0}^{-1}{{\rm Li}_{2}\left(\alpha\right) \over 1 - \alpha}\,{\rm d}\alpha
=\ln\left(2\right){\rm Li}_{2}\left(-1\right) -\int_{0}^{-1}\ln\left(1 - \alpha\right)\,{\rm Li}_{2}'\left(\alpha\right)\,{\rm d}\alpha
=\ln\left(2\right){\rm Li}_{2}\left(-1\right) +\int_{0}^{-1}{\ln^{2}\left(1 - \alpha\right) \over \alpha}\,{\rm d}\alpha
$$

Comment: Thanks @FelixMarin. Now I'm becoming a Li fan like you! $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @Tunk-Fey They are quite nice.

Answer (score 0):

An elementary evaluation:
\begin{align}
I
&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{(1+xy)}}{1-xy}\overset{t=xy}{dy}\ dx \\
&=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\ln{(1+t)}}{1-t}dt\ {d} {(\ln x)}\
\overset{ibp} =-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln{(1+x)}\ln x}{1-x} dx\\
\end{align}
Then, consider $K(a)= \int_0^1 \frac{ \ln x\ln(1-ax)}{x(1+x)}dx$
\begin{align}
K’(a) &=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{(1+x)(1-ax)}dx\\
&= -\frac{1}{1+a}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x}dx + \int_0^1\frac{a\ln x}{1-ax} \overset{ax\to y}{dx }\right)\\
&= \frac{\zeta(2)}{2(1+a)} - \frac{\ln a\ln(1-a)}{1+a}- \frac1{1+a}\int_0^a\frac{\ln y}{1-y}dy\\
\end{align}
to establish

\begin{align}
0&=K( 0)
=K(1)-\int_0^1 K’(a)da \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{x(1+x)} {dx} 
 - \frac12\zeta(2)\int_0^1 \frac1{1+a}da \\
& \hspace{10mm} +\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x} dx+\int_0^1 \frac1{1+a}\int_0^a\frac{\ln y}{1-y}dy \ \overset{ibp}{da}\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{x}dx 
 - \frac12\zeta(2)\ln2 +\ln2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln y}{1-y}dy -I\\
 &= \zeta(3)-\frac32 \zeta(2)\ln2-I
\end{align}

which leads to

$$I= \zeta(3) -\frac32 \zeta(2)\ln2 $$