# A cute limit $\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\left(\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\right)+\log(2)H_m\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

I'm sure that for many of you this is a limit pretty easy to compute, but my concern here
is a bit different, and I'd like to know if I can nicely compute it without using special functions. Do you have in mind such ways?

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\left(\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\right)+\log(2)H_m\right)$$

Comment: I see nothing cute here... Also, what is $H_m$?

Comment: Isn't $\log(2) H_m$ constant in the sum?

Comment: @5xum http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html

Comment: The limit is $\displaystyle\;\frac{\pi^2}{12} - \frac{\log^2 2}{2}\;$. All you need is taylor expansion of $\log(1+t)$ and the well known identity $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{nk}+H_m\log(2)\right)
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^m\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{nk}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{nk}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{nk}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{H_k}k\\
&=\frac12\zeta(2)-\frac12\log(2)^2
\end{align}
$$
the last step is from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/499689) where only series manipulations are used, no special functions.

Comment: @robjohn I see you are a legend at summations. Can you tell me from where I can learn all the tricks you use?

Comment: @AdityaKumar: experience from computing many sums.