# A sum of six alternating harmonic series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

In one of the answers to this question [Evaluate $\int_0^1\arcsin^2(\frac{\sqrt{-x}}{2}) (\log^3 x) (\frac{8}{1+x}+\frac{1}{x}) \, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4592985), the OP also presents some results from a paper, many of them *obviously* related to sums of harmonic series of weight $6$ (perhaps also magical cancellations involving some of the closed forms prevent me from saying more).

Here is an example of a sum that is strongly related to those sums - in fact, to solve those questions elementarily one wants to get transformations (this may take some time and it can be a boring task) to such forms as the one below (this is just one example)

> \begin{equation*}
>  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n}{n^5} -\frac{3}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n^2}{n^4} +\frac{4}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n^3}{n^3}-\frac{2}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n^4}{n^2}
> \end{equation*}
> \begin{equation*}
> +\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n^3}-\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n H_n^{(3)}}{n^2}
> \end{equation*}
> \begin{equation*}
> =\frac{19}{128} \zeta (6)+\frac{1}{16}\zeta^2(3).
> \end{equation*}

Since the previous question with such questions had been well received, maybe the community will enjoy some more sums of series alike, leading to very simple and neat closed forms.

The sum of the series above is proposed by C. I. Valean, and it is obtained very elegantly - such a solution will be presented **here** after the release of **More (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, the sequel of **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**.

How would you attack it?

Comment: "the OP also presents some results from a paper...." which paper precisely?

Comment: @pisco You referred to https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.4298 in your answer at the given MSE link, right in the beginning, "This paper of 2010 conjectured many infinite sums. The following are the most difficult among them:"

Comment: I see. Except for a few of them, many identities conjectured there (all proved now) are not quite on the same level of difficulty as those you posted on this site or in your books. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.07238.pdf contains some new conjectures (some are also proved now) of the same author, you might be interested in them.

Comment: The identity of this question seems quite unrelated to those papers. All 6 sums can be expressed in terms of $\text{Li}_n(1/2)$ or $\text{Li}_n((1+i)/2)$. Although in my proof of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4592985, one needs to evaluate thousand to million such combinations you asked.

Comment: @pisco From a personal perspective, if I cannot solve a problem with an artistic approach, then it is in some sense as if it is not solved at all.

Comment: @pisco As regards the series presented in the paper, I'll share more after finalizing some of the work on them. As long as I enjoy a problem, no level of (suggested) difficulty can ever prevent me from giving it a try (and I never give up easily).

Comment: @pisco btw, thanks for the paper! There is always a moment of joy to see around more challenging problems with series! :-)

Comment: I look forward to read your accessible proofs (hopefully they'll be self-contained and within a few pages)