# A series involving harmonic numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

Does anyone know the exact value of this:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k\frac{H_k}{k}
$$
or this:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k\frac{H_k^{(2)}}{k}
$$
Thanks!

---

Thanks again for the answers! I found very interesting that the integral gives exact values up to r=3 but from 4 this integral gives not exact values:

$$
\int_{-1}^0 \frac{Li_4(t)}{t(1-t)} \mathrm{d}t
$$

because wolfram says that "no results found in terms of standard mathematical functions"

Comment: [I have given an answer here in my previous avatar, not just for this sum but also for more general sums.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275643/proving-an-alternating-euler-sum-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k1-h-kk)

Answer (score 3):

[From my answer in my previous avatar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275643/proving-an-alternating-euler-sum-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k1-h-kk), denoting
$$A(p,q) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}H_k^{(p)}}{k^q}$$
we have
$$A(1,1) = \dfrac{\zeta(2)-\log^2(2)}2$$
and
$$A(2,1) = \zeta(3) - \dfrac{\zeta(2)\log(2)}2$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

One of the usual tactics is to exploit the generating function for harmonic numbers:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}H_{n}^{(r)}t^n=\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{r}{\left(t\right)}}{1-t};~~~\small{\left[\left|t\right|<1\right]}.$$

Dividing both sides by $t$ and integrating from $0$ to $x$, we have:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}^{(r)}x^{n}}{n}
&=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{r}{\left(t\right)}}{t\left(1-t\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x.\\
\end{align}$$

Thus, to find the values of your sums, you simply set $x$ to an appropriate value and solve the integral on the RHS.

Comment: So in the second formula I choose x to be -1 in this case.

Comment: "Li" means the logarithmic integral funtion? 
How can I calculate the value of the integral?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first is (6*Log[2]^2 - Pi^2)/12, obtained by calling on algorithms for symbolic summation included in Mathematica.

Input:  Sum[((-1)^k*HarmonicNumber[k])/k, {k, 1, Infinity}]
Output: (-Pi^2 + 6*Log[2]^2)/12

I am not sure what your superscript (2) means.

Comment: A derrivation would be nice along that.

Comment: Some of these symbolic algorithms have "certification methods" attached to them -- e.g., the Wilf-Zeilberger method. There are some add-on packages for Mathematica that show such certificates. This is probably not what you mean exactly by "derivation method". But the fact is that it does become a fully automated proof. Some computer algorithms allow such certifications, others do not.  Once should always check numerically that the symbolic result returned agrees with the numeric approximation, of course.