# How do I integrate $\int_0^1\arctan(x)\log(\frac{1-x}{1+x})\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

I've recently come across an interesting integral, which is of the form:

$$\int_0^1\arctan(x)\log\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$

To start, I expanded the arctangent into its series expansion, then utilized the Weierstraß substitution in order to remove the fractional term from the logarithm:

$$t = \frac{1-x}{1+x}$$

Finally, I'm left with this integral:

$$2 \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} \int_0^1 \frac{(1-t)^{2k+1}}{(1+t)^{2k+3}} \log(t)\mathrm{d}t$$

Which looks an **awful** lot like the beta function, namely:

$$B(x, y) = (1-a)^y \int_0^1 \frac{(1-t)^{x-1} t^{y-1}}{(1-at)^{x+y}} \mathrm{d}t, \quad a \leq 1$$

For the following values, the integrals are **nearly** identical:

$$a=-1,$$
$$x=2k+2,$$
$$y=1$$

However, this is the bit where I fail to make progress.

I see that the integrals are clearly just off by that logarithm, but I cannot find a relation between them in order to progress with this integral.

I've tried differentiating with respect to the parameter $y$ in order to bring in that logarithm, but that obviously doesn't do much - as the parameter also lies in the denominator and causes unwanted trouble.

I've also tried constructing integrals which are similar to this one, but only have the parameter $y$ in the numerator; however, I haven't been able to make much progress doing that either. These integrals end up looking nothing like the beta function.

Comment: From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830600/what-about-the-definite-integral-int-01-int-01-frac-operatornamearctanh?noredirect=1), maybe a duplicate, the integral is $\frac{\pi^2}{16}- \frac\pi4\ln(2)-C$ with Catalan’s constant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integrate by parts with $dx=d(x-1)$

\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\tan^{-1}x\ln\frac{1-x}{1+x}\ {dx}\\
\overset{ibp}= & \int_0^1 \frac{(1-x)\ln \frac{1-x}{1+x}}{1+x^2}\ \overset{\frac{1-x}{1+x}\to x}{dx}
-2\int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}x}{1+x}dx\\
=& \ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx -\frac34 \int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x}dx
 -2\int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}x}{1+x}dx\\
=& -G-\frac34 \left(-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right)-2\cdot \frac\pi8\ln2
=-G +\frac{\pi^2}{16} -\frac\pi4\ln2
\end{align}
where $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx=-G$ and [$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x}dx= -\frac{\pi^2}{12} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3826136/686284)

Comment: How do I see the curious $\int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}x}{1+x}dx = \frac{\pi}{8} \log(2)$?

Comment: @196574 one could start by writing$$\tan^{-1}(x)=\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2y^2}\,dy$$

Comment: @user196574 $\int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}x}{1+x} \overset{x\to \frac{1-x}{1+x}}{dx}= \int_0^1 \frac{\frac\pi4-\tan^{-1}x}{1+x}dx=\frac\pi8\int_0^1 \frac1{1+x}dx= \frac\pi8\ln2
$

Comment: @Quanto Thanks, took me a minute, but that's very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Noting
$$ d\bigg[(x-1)\ln\bigg(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\bigg)-2\ln(1+x)\bigg]=\ln\bigg(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\bigg) $$
one has, by IBP,
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^1\tan^{-1}x\ln\bigg(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\bigg)\ {dx}\\
&=&-\int_0^1\bigg[(x-1)\ln\bigg(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\bigg)-2\ln(1+x)\bigg]\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx\\
&\overset{x\to\frac{1-x}{1+x}}{=}&\int_0^1\bigg(\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}+\frac{x\ln x}{1+x^2}-\frac{\ln x}{1+x}+\frac{2\ln(\frac2{1+x})}{1+x^2}\bigg)dx\\
&=&-G-\frac{\pi^2}{48}+\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac14\pi\ln2\\
&=&-G+\frac{\pi^2}{16}+\frac14\pi\ln2.
\end{eqnarray}
Update: Let
\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\\
&=&\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x}{(1+tx)(1+x^2)}dtdx\\
&=&\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x}{(1+tx)(1+x^2)}dxdt\\
&=&\int_0^1\bigg(\frac\pi4\frac{t}{1+t^2}+\frac{2\ln2}{1+x^2}-\frac{1+t}{1+t^2}\bigg)dt\\
&=&\frac14\pi\ln2-I
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ I=\frac18\pi\ln2. $$
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^1\frac{2\ln(\frac2{1+x})}{1+x^2}\\
&=&\frac{\pi}2\ln2-2I=\frac{\pi}4\ln2.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Where is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^1 \arctan(x)\log\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right) \, dx \\
&= 2 \int_0^1 \arctan\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right) \log(y) \, \frac{dy}{(1+y)^2} \tag1 \\
&= \frac\pi2 \int_0^1 \frac{\log(y)}{(1+y)^2} \, dy - 2 \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(y)\log(y)}{(1+y)^2} \, dy}_J \tag2 \\[2ex]
J &= \int_0^1 \left(\frac{\log(y)}{(1+y^2)(1+y)} + \frac{\arctan(y)}{y(1+y)}\right) \, dy \tag3 \\
&= \frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\log(y)}{1+y} \, dy + \frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{1-y}{1+y^2} \log(y) \, dy \tag4 \\
&\quad\quad + \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(y)}y \, dy - \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(y)}{1+y} \, dy \\
&= - \frac\pi4\log(2) + \frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\log(y)}{1+y} \, dy \\
&\quad\quad - \frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{1+y}{1+y^2} \log(y) \, dy + \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+y)}{1+y^2} \, dy \tag3
\end{align*}$$

---

- $(1)$ : substitute $x=\dfrac{1-y}{1+y}$
- $(2)$ : $\arctan\left(\dfrac{1-y}{1+y}\right) = \dfrac\pi4-\arctan(y)$ for $y>-1$
- $(3)$ : integrate by parts
- $(4)$ : partial fractions

---

The remaining integrals can all be computed by invoking the series expansion of $\dfrac1{1-y}$ and integrating by parts:

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{\log(y)}{1+y} \, dy &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \int_0^1 y^n \log(y) \, dy \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} \\
&= -\frac{\pi^2}{12} \\[2ex]
\int_0^1 \frac{\log(y)}{(1+y)^2} \, dy &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n \int_0^1 y^n \log(y) \, dy \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n \\
&= \log(2) \\[2ex]
\int_0^1 \frac{1+y}{1+y^2} \log(y) \, dy &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \int_0^1 \left(y^{2n} + y^{2n+1}\right) \log(y) \, dy \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \left(\frac1{(2n+1)^2} + \frac1{(2n+2)^2}\right) \\
&= -G - \frac{\pi^2}{48}
\end{align*}$$

The last integral requires a bit of massaging first; to that end, reuse/undo the substitution from step $(1)$.

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+y)}{1+y^2} \, dy &= \int_0^1 \frac{\log(2)-\log(1+y)}{1+y^2} \, dy \tag{$-1$} \\
\implies 2 \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+y)}{1+y^2} \, dy &= \log(2) \int_0^1 \frac{dy}{1+y^2} \\
\implies \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+y)}{1+y^2} \, dy &= \frac\pi8\log(2)
\end{align*}$$

---

Putting everything together, we ultimately find

$$I = \boxed{\frac{\pi^2}{16} - G - \frac\pi4 \log(2)}$$