# prove that $\int_{0}^{1}\Big(\frac{\operatorname{li}(x)}{x}\Big)^2dx= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Tags: improper-integrals, riemann-zeta, pi, polylogarithm

prove that :

$$\int_{0}^{1}\Big(\frac{\operatorname{li}(x)}{x}\Big)^2dx< \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Where $\operatorname{li}(x)$ denotes [the logarithm integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function) .

The inequality is very very sharp .I have tried integration by parts and power series but we need a lot of terms to get the result.So i was thinking to another methods.Since we have an integral representation of $\zeta(2)$ why not make a comparison of two functions?

It's the kind of result which is misleading (is there a question for that I think yes )

So if you have a tricky way you are very welcome .

Any helps is greatly appreciated .

Thanks a lot for your contributions.

### Update :

I work with WA wich gives a difference between this two quantities
So I'm really lost to prove this :

$$\int_{0}^{1}\Big(\frac{\operatorname{li}(x)}{x}\Big)^2dx= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

### My work :

The integral is equivalent to :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{li}^2\Big(\frac{x}{x+1}\Big)}{x^2}dx$$

The next idea is to apply the [RMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem) but I can't find a power series to the function :$f(x)=\operatorname{li}^2\Big(\frac{x}{x+1}\Big)$

### My question:

can someone  achieve my work ?

Comment: It appears that this is an exact equality, not an inequality.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Mouarf Wolfram alpha is misleading so ...

Comment: Appears as a part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2867310).

Comment: @Metamorphy can we use the Ramanujan master theorem ?

Comment: You're welcome to edit the question to make one see how. I didn't think that much about it. The cited approach looks somewhat more elementary.

Comment: @metamorphy oh you know it's just a question but I think it doesn't work with that ...To be continued.Thanks for the edit and your interest .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also don't know how to find the series required to apply Ramanujan's master theorem, but here's the simpler method from [my old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2866629/show-that-int-01-4-space-operatornamelix3-space-x-1-space-x-3-dx/2867310#2867310):

We have
$$ \mathrm{e}^{t} - 1 = \sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!} \, , \, t \in \mathbb{R} \, , ~ \stackrel{t = \ln(x)}{\Leftrightarrow} ~ x - 1 = \sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\ln^k(x)}{k!} \, , \, x > 0 \, .$$
Therefore, we can integrate by parts twice and use $\operatorname{li}' = \frac{1}{\ln}$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\int \limits_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{li}^2(x)}{x^2} \, \mathrm{d} x &= \left[\operatorname{li}^2(x) \left(1 - \frac{1}{x}\right) \right]_{x=0}^{x=1} - \int \limits_0^1 2 \operatorname{li}(x) \operatorname{li}'(x) \left(1 - \frac{1}{x}\right) \, \mathrm{d} x \\
&= 0 + 2 \int \limits_0^1 \frac{-\operatorname{li}(x)}{x} \frac{x-1}{\ln(x)} \mathrm{d} x = 2 \sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \int \limits_0^1 -\operatorname{li}(x) \frac{\ln^{k-1}(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d} x \\
&= 2 \sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \left\{\left[-\operatorname{li}(x) \frac{\ln^k(x)}{k}\right]_{x=0}^{x=1} - \int \limits_0^1 -\operatorname{li}'(x) \frac{\ln^k(x)}{k} \mathrm{d} x \right\} \\
&= 2 \sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \left\{0 + \frac{1}{k} \int \limits_0^1 \ln^{k-1}(x)\mathrm{d} x \right\} \stackrel{x = \mathrm{e}^{-u}}{=} 2 \sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k! k} \int \limits_0^\infty u^{k-1} \mathrm{e}^{-u} \, \mathrm{d} u \\
&= 2 \sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k! k} (k-1)! = 2 \sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^2} = 2 \operatorname{\eta}(2) = 2 \frac{\pi^2}{12} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \, ,
\end{align}
where $\eta$ is the [Dirichlet eta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletEtaFunction.html). Interchanging summation and integration can be justified using the dominated convergence theorem.