# Help with $-\int_0^1 \ln(1+x)\ln(1-x)dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, digamma-function

I have been attempting to evaluate this integral and by using wolfram alpha I know that the value is$$I=-\int_0^1 \ln(1+x)\ln(1-x)dx=\frac{\pi^2}{6}+2\ln(2)-\ln^2(2)-2$$

My Attempt:

I start off by parametizing the integral as $$I(a)=\int_0^1 -\ln(1+x)\ln(1-ax)dx$$
where $I=I(1)$. I then differentiate to get $$I'(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{ax\ln(1+x)}{1-ax}dx=\int_0^1 ax\ln(1+x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty(ax)^ndx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^{n+1}\int_0^1 x^{n+1}\ln(1+x)dx$$

Evaluating this integral by integration by parts and geometric series I get
$$\int_0^1 x^{n+1}\ln(1+x)dx=\frac{x^{n+2}}{n+2}\ln(1+x)|_0^1-\frac{1}{n+2}\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n+2}}{1+x}dx=\frac{\ln(2)}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+2}\int_0^1 x^{n+2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-x)^kdx=\frac{\ln(2)}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\int_0^1 x^{k+n+2}dx=\frac{\ln(2)}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k+n+2}=\frac{\ln(2)}{n+2}-\frac{1}{2(n+2)}\left(\psi_0\left(\frac{n}{2}+2\right)-\psi_0\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)$$ So I arrive at $$I'(a)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^{n+1}\left(\frac{\ln(2)}{n+2}-\frac{1}{2(n+2)}\left(\psi_0\left(\frac{n}{2}+2\right)-\psi_0\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)\right)$$
Re-indexing I get
$$I'(a)=\frac{\ln(2)}{a}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\psi_0\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{n}a^{n-1}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\psi_0\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}{n}a^{n-1}$$Integrating both sides from $0$ to $1$ I recover $I(1)$
$$I(1)=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(2)}{a}\left(-\ln(1-a)-a\right)da+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\psi_0\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{n^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\psi_0\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}{n^2}$$ Then using the integral equation for the Dilogarithm I arrive at
$$I(1)=\ln(2)\int_0^1 -\frac{\ln(1-a)}{a}da-\ln(2)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\psi_0\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{n^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\psi_0\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}{n^2}$$
$$I(1)=\frac{\ln(2)\pi^2}{6}-\ln(2)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\psi_0\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{n^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\psi_0\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}{n^2}$$

At this point I could not continue further as I did not know how to simplify the Digamma terms in the sums. I think that by using the Digamma function's relation to the Harmonic Numbers it could be possible to exploit known values of Harmonic sums to arrive at the answer but I could not get the sums in a form where this would work. If anyone could help me continue further or let me know if I am on the right track I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try this link here: https://www.integral-calculator.com/ . It solves (almost) any integral and shows the steps it followed to do so.

Comment: Do what michail vazaios did suggest and just ask for the antiderivative. Look at the steps : it is just clear, simple and beautiful !

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I see, is there anyway to evaluate the integral using the method i followed? Or can it only be evaluated as demonstrated by the integral calculator?

Comment: Generalizations: $$\int_0^1 \log ^3(1-x) \log ^3(x+1) \, dx=36 \zeta (3)^2+12 \pi ^2 \zeta (3)-216 \zeta (3)-144 \zeta (5)+36 \zeta (3) \log ^3(2)-108 \zeta (3) \log ^2(2)-12 \pi ^2 \zeta (3) \log (2)+216 \zeta (3) \log (2)+144 \zeta (5) \log (2)-\pi ^4-36 \pi ^2-\frac{23 \pi ^6}{420}+720+\log ^6(2)-6 \log ^5(2)-\frac{3}{2} \pi ^2 \log ^4(2)+30 \log ^4(2)+6 \pi ^2 \log ^3(2)-120 \log ^3(2)-\frac{1}{2} \pi ^4 \log ^2(2)-18 \pi ^2 \log ^2(2)+360 \log ^2(2)+\pi ^4 \log (2)+36 \pi ^2 \log (2)-720 \log (2)$$

Answer (score 11):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{I \equiv
> -\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 + x}\ln\pars{1 - x}\,\dd x =
> {\pi^{2} \over 6} + 2\ln\pars{2} - \ln^{2}\pars{2} - 2:\ {\LARGE ?}}$.

\begin{align}
I & \equiv
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 + x}\ln\pars{1 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}{\bracks{\ln\pars{1 - x} - \ln\pars{1 + x}}^{\, 2} -
\bracks{\ln\pars{1 - x} + \ln\pars{1 + x}}^{\, 2} \over 4}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\underbrace{{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x \over
1 + x}\,\dd x}_{\ds{\equiv\ \mc{I}_{1}}}\ -\
\underbrace{{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{\equiv\ \mc{I}_{2}}}\ =\
\mc{I}_{1} - \mc{I}_{2}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

> $\ds{\Large\mc{I}_{1}:\ ?}$

\begin{align}
\mc{I}_{1} & \equiv
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x \over 1 + x}\,\dd x
\,\,\,\stackrel{\pars{1 - x}/\pars{1 + x}\ =\ t}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{t} \over \pars{1 + t}^{2}}
\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\underbrace{-2 \choose n}
_{\ds{\pars{n + 1}\pars{-1}^{n}}}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}\ln^{2}\pars{t}t^{n}\,\dd t}
_{\ds{2 \over \pars{n +1}^{3}}}\ =\
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\over n^{2}} =
\bbx{\pi^{2} \over 12}\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

---

> $\ds{\Large\mc{I}_{2}:\ ?}$

\begin{align}
\mc{I}_{2} & \equiv
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x
\,\,\,\stackrel{x^{2}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over 8}\int_{0}^{1}x^{-1/2}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\left.{1 \over 8}\,\partiald[2]{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}x^{-1/2}
\pars{1 - x}^{\mu}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 0} =
{1 \over 8}\,\partiald[2]{}{\mu}\bracks{\Gamma\pars{1/2}\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + 3/2}}_{\ \mu\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{-\,{\pi^{2} \over 12} - 2\ln\pars{2} + \ln^{2}\pars{2} + 2}
\label{3}\tag{3}
\end{align}

> \eqref{1}, \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} yield the coveted result
>   $\ds{\bbx{{\pi^{2} \over 6} + 2\ln\pars{2} - \ln^{2}\pars{2} - 2}}$.

---

$\ds{\LARGE\mbox{Another Approach}}$

---

\begin{align}
I & \equiv
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 + x}\ln\pars{1 - x}\,\dd x}
\,\,\,\stackrel{x + 1\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
-\int_{1}^{2}\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{2 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{x/2\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
-2\int_{1/2}^{1}\bracks{\ln\pars{x} + \ln\pars{2}}
\bracks{\ln\pars{1 - x} + \ln\pars{2}}\,\dd x
\\[8mm] & =
-2\int_{1/2}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x}\,\dd x -
2\ln\pars{2}\
\overbrace{\int_{1/2}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x}^{\ds{\ln\pars{2} - 1 \over 2}}
\\[2mm] &
-2\ln\pars{2}\
\underbrace{\int_{1/2}^{1}\ln\pars{1 - x}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{-\,{\ln\pars{2} + 1 \over 2}}} -
2\ln^{2}\pars{2}\int_{1/2}^{1}\,\dd x
\\[8mm] & =
-2\int_{1/2}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x}\,\dd x +
2\ln\pars{2} - \ln^{2}\pars{2}
\end{align}
The remaining integral is evaluated with
[Euler Reflection Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm). Namely,
\begin{align}
I & \equiv
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 + x}
\ln\pars{1 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
-2\int_{1/2}^{1}\bracks{{\pi^{2} \over 6} - \mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x} - \mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 - x}}\dd x +
2\ln\pars{2} - \ln^{2}\pars{2}
\\ & \pars{~\mrm{Li}_{2}:\ Dilogarithm~}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{\pi^{2} \over 6} +
2\int_{0}^{1}\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x}\dd x  +
2\ln\pars{2} - \ln^{2}\pars{2}
\\[5mm] &
\stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\,
-\,{\pi^{2} \over 6} +
\braces{2\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1} -
2\int_{0}^{1}x\bracks{-\,{\ln\pars{1- x} \over x}}}\dd x  +
2\ln\pars{2} - \ln^{2}\pars{2}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{\pi^{2} \over 6} + 2\ln\pars{2} - \ln^{2}\pars{2} - 2}
\qquad\qquad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\pi^{2} \over 6}
\\[1mm]
\ds{\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{x}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\,{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, this time using [Mike Spivey's alternating Euler sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275643/proving-an-alternating-euler-sum-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k1-h-kk):

\begin{align*}
I &=-\int_0^1\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)\,\mathrm dx \\ 
 &= \int_0^1\ln(1-x)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}x^n\,\mathrm dx,\qquad\text{Mercator series}\\ 
 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\int_0^1\ln(1-x)x^n\,\mathrm dx\\ 
 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\left[ \int_0^1(1-x)^\alpha x^n\,\mathrm dx\right ]\Bigg\vert_{\alpha=0}\\ 
 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha} \text{B}\left(\alpha+1,\,n+1 \right )\Bigg\vert_{\alpha=0},\qquad\text{beta function}\\ 
 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\cdot\left[ \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)\Gamma(n+1)\left(\psi(\alpha+1)-\psi(\alpha+n+2) \right )}{\Gamma(\alpha+n+2)}\right ]\Bigg\vert_{\alpha=0}\\ 
 &= -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\cdot\frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1},\qquad\text{used }\psi(1)=-\gamma\text{ and }\psi(m)=H_{m-1}-\gamma\\ 
 &= -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n+1}}{n}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n+1}}{n+1}\\ 
 &= -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n(n+1)}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n+1}}{n+1}\\ 
 &= -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n}-1+2\ln(2)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n+1}}{n+1}\\
 &= -2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n}-2+2\ln(2)\\
 &= \frac{\pi^2}{6}+2\ln(2)-\ln^2(2)-2,\qquad\text{applied Mike's sum.}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}J&=\int_0^1 \ln(1+x)\ln(1-x)\,dx\\
&=\Big[\left(\left(1+x\right)\ln(1+x)-x-2\ln 2+1\right)\ln(1-x)\Big]_0^1+\int_0^1\frac{\left(1+x\right)\ln(1+x)-x-2\ln 2+1}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\left(1+x\right)\ln(1+x)-x-2\ln 2+1}{1-x}\,dx\\
\end{align}
Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$,
\begin{align}J&=\int_0^1\frac{\frac{2\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}-\frac{1-x}{1+x}-2\ln 2+1}{x(1+x)}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\frac{2\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}+\frac{2x}{1+x}-2\ln 2}{x(1+x)}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\frac{2\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}+\frac{2x}{1+x}-2\ln 2}{x}\,dx-\int_0^1\frac{\frac{2\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}+\frac{2x}{1+x}-2\ln 2}{1+x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\frac{2\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}+\frac{2x}{1+x}-2\ln 2}{x}\,dx+2+2\ln^2 2-4\ln 2\\
&=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{2\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+x}\right)}{x(1+x)}-\frac{2\ln 2}{x}\right)\,dx+2+2\ln^2 2-2\ln 2\\
&=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{2\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+x}\right)}{x}-\frac{2\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}-\frac{2\ln 2}{x}\right)\,dx+2+2\ln^2 2-2\ln 2\\
&=-2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\,dx-2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}\,dx+2+2\ln^2 2-2\ln 2\\
&=-2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\,dx+2+\ln^2 2-2\ln 2\\
\end{align}
But,
\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln(1-x^2)}{x^2}\,dx-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\,dx\end{align}
In the second integral perform the change of variable $y=x^2$,
\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\,dx&=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\,dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\times -\frac{\pi^2}{6}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{12}
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}\boxed{J=2+2\ln^2 2-2\ln 2-\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}}\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Proceed as follows
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 \ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)\,dx \\
=&\int_0^1\ln2 \ln(1-x)dx +\int_0^1 \ln(1-x)\ln\frac{1+x}2 \ \overset{ibp}{dx}\\
=&-\ln2 +1 -\int_0^1 \ln\frac{1+x}2dx+\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x}dx +\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\frac{1+x}2}{1-x}\overset{ibp}{dx}\\
=& 2-2\ln2 +2 \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x}\overset{x=\frac{1-t}{1+t}}{dx} \\
=&2-2\ln2 +2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln2-\ln(1+t)+\ln t}{1+t}dt\\
=& 2-2\ln2 +\ln^22-\frac{\pi^2}6
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Some other basic method:
$$\int_0^1 -\log(1+x)\log(1-x) \, {\rm d}x \\
= (1-x)\log(1+x)\log(1-x)\Big|_0^1 - \int_0^1 (1-x) \left[ \frac{\log(1-x)}{1+x} - \frac{\log(1+x)}{1-x}\right] {\rm d}x  \\
\stackrel{t=1-x}{=} (1+x)\left[\log(1+x)-1\right] \Big|_0^1 - \int_0^1 \frac{t/2 \cdot \log t}{1-t/2} \, {\rm d}t \\
=2\log 2 - 1 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 (t/2)^n \log t \, {\rm d}t \\
=2\log 2-1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{-n}}{(n+1)^2} \\
=2\log 2 - 2 + 2\,{\rm Li_2}(1/2) \\
=2\log 2 - 2 + \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \log^22
$$